# Is micro-optimization worth the time?

Tags: php, performance, optimization

I am a PHP developer and I have always thought that micro-optimizations are not worth the time. If you really need that extra performance, you would either write your software so that it's architecturally faster, or you write a C++ extension to handle slow tasks (or better yet, compile the code using HipHop). However, today a work mate told me that there is a big difference in

```
is_array($array)
```

and

```
$array === (array) $array
```

and I was like "eh, that's a pointless comparison really", but he wouldn't agree with me.. and he is the best developer in our company and is taking charge of a website that does about 50 million SQL queries per day -- for instance. So, I am wondering here: could he be wrong or is micro-optimization really worth the time and when?

Comment: Just being the best developer in a company doesn't have to mean much. At least in numerous The Daily WTF stories those are the ones who do the most insanely weird things ;-)

Comment: The number of queries could probably be reduced by using stored procedures and preventing round trips... *that's* an optimisation...

Comment: As far as the assertion about one expression being preferable to the other, this comment on the PHP doc site makes the same claim, but the test seems to be somewhat flawed (if I understand PHP right, it'll only every test the $test array due to short circuit evaluation). I wonder if the same results hold if the item being tested isn't an array?: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php#98156

Comment: cleaning a carburetor will certainly improve a car's performance. but installing a fuel-injection system will be more efficient. if you'll be using your car to drive 3 blocks away, the carburetor will do. if you want to join the nascar, find a way to overhaul the entire engine.

Comment: WHat your work mate told you is a myth.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Micro-optimisation is worth it *when you have evidence that you're optimising a bottleneck*.

Usually it's not worth it - write the most readable code you can, and use realistic benchmarks to check the performance. If and when you find you've got a bottleneck, micro-optimise just that bit of code (measuring as you go). Sometimes a small amount of micro-optimisation can make a huge difference.

But *don't* micro-optimise *all* your code... it will end up being far harder to maintain, and you'll quite possibly find you've either missed the real bottleneck, or that your micro-optimisations are *harming* performance instead of helping.

Comment: Completely agree.  Is it worth the time?  You'll know for your app, because you can profile and you'll see where the optimizations will give enough benefit back.

To answer a different question, "Should you micro-optimize everything?"  Absolutely not.  Clearly-read & maintained code is vastly more important in most cases than fast code that is not performance sensitive.

Programming is all about compromise and balance.  Code complexity, maintainability, performance, programmer time-cost, hardware requirements-cost.  And most times, dev time & bugs are much more costly than hardware.

Comment: @Jon - Can you get back to writing books about C# etc that I love to read and leave the low hanging fruit to us mere mortals????

Comment: @Peter: If it's any consolation, I'm currently going over the proofs of chapter 14 of C# in Depth. SO is just an occasional distraction :)

Comment: Oh no, he is going for the PHP badge, too!

Comment: @Jon - you call a SO rep of 205K an **occasional** distraction?????  But I do look forward to reading your next book.  The original C# in Depth reminded me of Scott Meyers' C++ books which I liked a lot.

Comment: @Jon: If you're saying anything in your book about profiling, I hope you're giving some thought to these issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343

Comment: @Mike: Nope, I say very little indeed about profiling in the book.

Answer (score 142):

Well, for a trivially small array, `$array === (array) $array` is significantly faster than `is_array($array)`.  On the order of over 7 times faster.  But each call is only on the order of `1.0 x 10 ^ -6` seconds (`0.000001 seconds`).  So unless you're calling it literally thousands of times, it's not going to be worth it.  And if you are calling it thousands of times, I'd suggest you're doing something wrong...

The difference comes when you're dealing with a large array.  Since `$array === (array) $array` requires a new variable to be copied requires the array to be iterated over internally for the comparison, it'll likely be SIGNIFICANTLY slower for a large array.  For example, on an array with 100 integer elements, `is_array($array)` is within a margin of error (`< 2%`) of `is_array()` with a small array (coming in at `0.0909` seconds for 10,000 iterations).  But `$array = (array) $array` is extremely slow.  For only 100 elements, it's already over twice as slow as `is_array()` (coming in at `0.203` seconds).  For 1000 elements, `is_array` stayed the same, yet the cast comparison increased to `2.0699` seconds...

The reason it's faster for small arrays is that `is_array()` has the overhead of being a function call, where the cast operation is a simple language construct...  And iterating over a small variable (in C code) will typically be cheaper than the function call overhead.  But, for larger variables, the difference grows...

It's a tradeoff.  If the array is small enough, iteration will be more efficient.  But as the size of the array grows, it will becomes increasingly slower (and hence the function call will become faster).

### Another Way To Look At It

Another way to look at it would be to examine the algorithmic complexity of each cast.

Let's take a look at `is_array()` first. It's [source code](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/standard/type.c#298) basically shows it's an `O(1)` operation. Meaning it's a constant time operation. But we also need to look at the function call. In PHP, function calls with a single array parameter are either `O(1)` or `O(n)` depending on if copy-on-write needs to be triggered. If you call `is_array($array)` when `$array` is a variable reference, copy-on-write will be triggered and a full copy of the variable will occur.

So therefore `is_array()` is a best case `O(1)` and worst-case `O(n)`. But as long as you're not using references, it's always `O(1)`...

The cast version, on the other hand, does two operations. It does a cast, then it does an equality check. So let's look at each separately. The cast operator [handler](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_vm_def.h#3679) first forces [a copy](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_vm_def.h#3690) of the input variable. No matter if it's a reference or not. So simply using the `(array)` casting operator forces an `O(n)` iteration over the array to cast it (via the copy_ctor call).

Then, it converts the new copy to an array. This is `O(1)` for arrays and primitives, but `O(n)` for objects.

Then, the identical operator executes. The [handler](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_vm_def.h#148) is just a proxy to the [`is_identical_function()`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_operators.c#1642). Now, is_identical will short-circuit if `$array` is not an array. Therefore, it has a *best case* of `O(1)`. But if `$array` **is** an array, it can short-circuit again if the hash tables are identical (meaning both variables are copy-on-write copies of each other). So that case is `O(1)` as well. But remember that we forced a copy above, so we can't do that if it's an array. So it's `O(n)` thanks to [zend_hash_compare](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_hash.c#1484)...

So the end result is this table of worst-case runtime:

```
+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|          | array | array+ref | non-array | non-array+ref |
+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| is_array |  O(1) |    O(n)   |    O(1)   |     O(n)      |
+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| (array)  |  O(n) |    O(n)   |    O(n)   |     O(n)      |
+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
```

Note that it looks like they scale the same for references. They don't. They both scale *linearly* for referenced variables. But the constant factor changes. For example, in a referenced array of size 5, is_array will perform 5 memory allocations, and 5 memory copies, followed by 1 type check. The cast version, on the other hand, will perform 5 memory allocations, 5 memory copies, followed by 2 type checks, followed by 5 type checks and 5 equality checks (`memcmp()` or the like). So `n=5` yields 11 ops for `is_array`, yet 22 ops for `===(array)`...

Now, `is_array()` does have the O(1) overhead of a stack push (due to the function call), but that'll only dominate runtime for extremely small values of `n` (we saw in the benchmark above just 10 array elements was enough to completely eliminate all difference).

### The Bottom Line

I'd suggest going for readability though.  I find `is_array($array)` to be far more readable than `$array === (array) $array`.  So you get the best of both worlds.

The script I used for the benchmark:

```
$elements = 1000;
$iterations = 10000;

$array = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $elements; $i++) $array[] = $i;

$s = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) is_array($array);
$e = microtime(true);
echo "is_array completed in " . ($e - $s) ." Seconds\n";

$s = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) $array === (array) $array;
$e = microtime(true);
echo "Cast completed in " . ($e - $s) ." Seconds\n";
```

**Edit:** For the record, these results were with 5.3.2 on Linux...

**Edit2:** Fixed the reason the array is slower (it's due to the iterated comparison instead of memory reasons).  See [compare_function](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/Zend/zend_operators.c?revision=306939&view=markup) for the iteration code...

Comment: +1. I guess that "best programmer" should be definitely presented with your answer and benchmark snippet.

Answer (score 12):

> Is micro-optimization worth the time?

No, unless it is.

In other words, *a-priori*, the answer is "no", but *after* you know a specific line of code consumes a healthy percent of clock time, then and only then is it worth optimizing.

In other words, profile first, because otherwise you don't have that knowledge. [This is the method I rely on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024), regardless of language or OS.

Added: When many programmers discuss performance, from experts on down, they tend to talk about "where" the program spends its time. There is a sneaky ambiguity in that "where" that *leads them away* from the things that could save the most time, namely, function call sites. After all, the "call Main" at the top of an app is a "place" that the program is almost never "at", but is responsible for 100% of the time. Now you're not going to get rid of "call Main", but there are nearly always other calls that you *can* get rid of.
While the program is opening or closing a file, or formatting some data into a line of text, or waiting for a socket connection, or "new"-ing a chunk of memory, or passing a notification throughout a large data structure, it is spending great amounts of time in *calls* to functions, but is that "where" it is? Anyway, those calls are quickly found with stack samples.

Comment: Re *"quickly found with stack samples"*: Yes, but very few people get this even though it is so simple (maybe that is the problem). For instance, it can (usually) be done in Visual Studio without any other tools needed.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: It's an education problem. I was a professor, 40 years ago, and I've seen it up close. Professors don't see much of really big code - they're into algorithms and big-O, which is fine as far as it goes. When the curriculum says "talk about profiling", they talk about `gprof` and its modern cousins. Having checked that off, they move on. What do students do? In class, their minds are open to being filled with wisdom. Then when they graduate, they think the roles are reversed - that it is their job to educate us dinosaurs what they've been taught. I'm sure you've seen that. :-)

Answer (score 6):

As the cliche goes, micro-optimization is generally worth the time only in the smallest, most performance-critical hotspots of your code, only after you've **proven** that's where the bottleneck is.  However, I'd like to flesh this out a little, to point out some exceptions and areas of misunderstanding.

1. This doesn't mean that performance should not be considered at all upfront.  I define micro-optimization as optimizations based on low-level details of the compiler/interpreter, the hardware, etc.  By definition, a micro-optimization does not affect big-O complexity.  **Macro**-optimizations should be considered upfront, especially when they have a major impact on high-level design.  For example, it's pretty safe to say that if you have a large, frequently accessed data structure, an O(N) linear search isn't going to cut it.  Even things that are only constant terms but have a large and obvious overhead might be worth considering upfront.  Two big examples are excessive memory allocation/data copying and computing the same thing twice when you could be computing it once and storing/reusing the result.
2. If you're doing something that's been done before in a slightly different context, there may be some bottlenecks that are so well-known that it's reasonable to consider them upfront.  For example, I was recently working on an implementation of the FFT (fast Fourier Transform) algorithm for the D standard library.  Since so many FFTs have been written in other languages before, it's very well-known that the biggest bottleneck is cache performance, so I went into the project immediately thinking about how to optimize this.

Answer (score 4):

In general you should not write any optimisation which makes your code more ugly or harder to understand; in my book this definitely falls into this category.

It is much harder to go back and change old code than write new code, because you have to do regression testing. So in general, no code already in production should be changed for frivolous reasons.

PHP is such an incredibly inefficient language that if you have performance problems, you should probably look to refactor hot spots so they execute less PHP code anyway.

So I'd say in general no, and in this case no, and in cases where you absolutely need it AND have measured that it makes a provable difference AND is the quickest win (low-hanging fruit), yes.

Certainly scattering micro-optimisations like this throughout your existing, working, tested code is a terrible thing to do, it will definitely introduce regressions and almost certainly make no noticable difference.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm going to assume that `is_array($array)` is the preferred way, and `$array === (array) $array` is the allegedly faster way (which bring up the question why isn't `is_array` implemented using that comparison, but I digress).

I will hardly ever go back into my code and insert a micro-optimization<sup>*</sup>, but I will often put them into the code as I write it, provided:

- it doesn't slow my typing down.
- the intent of the code is still clear.

That particular optimization fails on both counts.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> OK, actually I do, but that has more to do with me having a touch of OCD rather than good development practices.</sub>

Comment: Even though I'm not a PHP dev, and I know it's kind of besides the point of the actual question, but I'd appreciate someone (not necessarily James) commenting on why there's such a performance difference (assuming it's true) and the question that James brought up  (why isn't `is_array()` implemented using the fast comparison?).

Comment: @Michael: It will have to be someone besides me (I'm not a PHP dev either)

Comment: Understood; I tried to make the comment indicate that. Also I realize that this is really just an idle curiosity (as much as micro-optimizations may be evil, I'm still often curious about what's happening behind the scenes in various language constructs).

Comment: As to the question you brought up, the answer is: the premise is false. It's not faster (in general).

Answer (score 3):

We had one place where the optimisation was really helpful.

Here some comparison:

`is_array($v)` : 10 sec

`$v === (array)$v` : 3,3 sec

`($v.'') === 'Array'` : 2,6 sec

The last one does cast to string, an Array is always casted to a string with value 'Array'. This check will be wrong, if the $v is a string with value 'Array' (never happens in our case).

Comment: This was not a synthetic test, but part of an application run.

Comment: The type checking one (second snippet, 3.3 sec) is the _best_ approach IMO. The first one has the overhead of a function call, and the third one is difficult to just glance at and understand. However, for large arrays, it might have [serious performance issues](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3471356/2788872), since the value is copied.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's more things than speed to take into consideration. When you read that 'faster' alternative, do you instantly think "Oh, this is checking to see if the variable is an array", or do you think "...wtf"?

Because really - when considering this method, how often is it called? What is the exact speed benefit? Does this stack up when the array is larger or smaller? One cannot do optimizations without benchmarks.

Also, one shouldn't do optimizations if they reduce the readability of the code. In fact, reducing that amount of queries by a few hundred thousand (and this is often easier than one would think) or optimizing them if applicable would be much, much more beneficial to performance than this micro-optimization.

Also, don't be intimidated by the guy's experience, as others have said, and think for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**Micro-optimization is not worth it. Code readability is much more important than micro-optimization.**

Great [article about useless micro-optimization by Fabien Potencier](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/8/print-vs-echo-which-one-is-faster) (creator of the [Symfony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony) framework):

> print vs echo, which one is faster?
>
> Print uses one more opcode because it actually returns something. We
>   can conclude that echo is faster than print. But one opcode costs
>   nothing, really nothing. Even if a script have hundreds of calls to
>   print. I have tried on a fresh WordPress installation. The script
>   halts before it ends with a "Bus Error" on my laptop, but the number
>   of opcodes was already at more than 2.3 millions. Enough said.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, micro-optimizations are actually even more relevant than algorithmic optimizations today *if* you are working in a performance-critical field. This might be a big *if* because many people don't actually work in performance-critical areas even for performance-critical software since they might just be making high-level calls into a third party library which does the actual performance-critical work. For example, many people these days trying to write an image or video software might write non-performance-critical code expressing they want at the image level, not having to manually loop through several million pixels themselves at 100+ frames per second. The library does that for them.

When I say that micro-optimizations are more relevant than algorithmic ones today, I don't mean that, say, parallelized SIMD code that minimizes cache misses applying a bubble sort will beat an [introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) or [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). What I mean is that professionals don't bubble sort large input sizes.

If you take any reasonably high-level language today, of which I include C++, you already have your share of reasonably efficient general-purpose data structures and algorithms at your fingertips. There's no excuse unless you're a beginning computer science student just getting your feet wet and reinventing the most primitive of wheels to be applying quadratic complexity sorts to massive input sizes or linear-time searches which can be accomplished in constant-time with the appropriate data structures.

So once you get past this beginner level, performance-critical applications still have wildly varying performance characteristics. Why? Why would one video processing software have three times the frame rate and more interactive video previews than the other when the developers aren't doing anything extremely dumb algorithmically? Why would one server doing a very similar thing be able to handle ten times the queries with the same hardware? Why would this software load a scene in 5 seconds while the other takes 5 minutes loading the same data? Why would this beautiful game have silky smooth and consistent frame rates while the other one is uglier, more primitive-looking with its graphics and lighting, and stutters here and there while taking twice the memory?

And that boils down to micro-optimizations, not algorithmic differences. Furthermore our memory hierarchy today is so skewed in performance, making previous algorithms that were thought to be good a couple of decades ago no longer as good if they exhibit poor locality of reference.

So if you want to write competitively-efficient software today, far more often than not, that will boil down to things like multithreading, [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD), GPU, [GPGPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units), improving locality of reference with better memory access patterns (loop tiling, [SoA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA), hot/cold field splitting, etc.), maybe even optimizing for branch prediction in extreme cases, and so forth, not so much algorithmic breakthroughs unless you're tackling an extremely unexplored territory where no programmers have ventured before.

There are still occasionally algorithmic breakthroughs that are potential game changers, like [voxel-cone tracing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_illumination#List_of_methods) recently. But those are exceptions and the people who come up with these often invest their lives to R&D (they're generally not people writing and maintaining large scale codebases), and it still boils down to micro-optimizations whether voxel-cone tracing can be applied to real-time environments like games or not. If you aren't good at micro-optimizations, you simply won't get the adequate framerates even using these algorithmic breakthroughs.

Comment: Apologies, I got a bit ranty in this one. I'm obsessed with nuance and context and I get impatient sometimes with general rules of thumb. Even Knuth's original paper that lead to the popular quote that premature optimization is the root of all evil was a paper proposing a micro-optimization to optimize loops with goto instructions, but with great care to specify to use such optimizations sparingly, when they are needed and count, and with a profiler in hand (even going into a whole section of how Knuth believed that all compilers should come with a built-in profiler).

Comment: The main thing I think that takes a lifetime and then some to master is to prioritize effectively (we can all probably work on this better). The profiler helps counter that ugly programmer impulse to optimize everything which, often in practice, optimizes nothing and makes everything convoluted (often pessimizing more than optimizing). The vast majority of a codebase should be designed to be as easy to understand and maintain as possible for sure if our priorities are straight. But what is considered "micro" in the context of optimization can have far more than micro effects in loopy cases.