# Finding the max value of a property in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, json

I'm looking for a really quick, clean and efficient way to get the max "y" value in the following JSON slice:

```json
[
  {
    "x": "8/11/2009",
    "y": 0.026572007
  },
  {
    "x": "8/12/2009",
    "y": 0.025057454
  },
  {
    "x": "8/13/2009",
    "y": 0.024530916
  },
  {
    "x": "8/14/2009",
    "y": 0.031004457
  }
]
```

Is a for-loop the only way to go about it? I'm keen on somehow using `Math.max`.

Answer (score 1257, accepted):

To find the maximum `y` value of the objects in `array`:

```js
Math.max.apply(Math, array.map(function(o) { return o.y; }))
```

or in more modern JavaScript:

```js
Math.max(...array.map(o => o.y))
```

### Warning:

This method is not advisable, it is better to use reduce. With a large array, `Math.max` will be called with a large number of arguments, which can cause stack overflow.

Comment: Could you expand this answer to show how to return the object that the max value was found in? That would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Here is the fiddle! hope this will help to someone https://jsfiddle.net/45c5r246/

Comment: @MikeLyons if you still care about getting the actual object: https://jsfiddle.net/45c5r246/34/

Comment: FWIW my understanding is when you call apply on a function it executes the function with a specified value for `this` and a series of arguments specified as an array. The trick is that apply turns the array into a series of actual function arguments. So in this case it finally calls `Math.max(0.0265, 0.0250, 0.024, 0.031)` with the `this` of the function executed being `Math`. I can't see why it should be `Math` frankly, I don't think the function requires a valid `this`. Oh and here is a proper explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255138/how-does-the-math-max-apply-work

Comment: @DanielC `Math` as `this` is just because that is what it would be if you called it as `Math.max(a,b,c)`. I am 99% sure this is unneeded on any browser though.

Comment: `Math.max.apply(Math,Array)` returns the max value for the given array. `array.map(function(o){return o.y;})` returns an array of the y values from your objects. Then in the second line of the fiddle `array.find(function(o){ return o.y == valueReturnedByMathMax; })` you just look for the object containing that max value.

Comment: Careful to call this only when the array is not empty, otherwise the returned value will be `Infinity`

Comment: How  do you return the object with the highest value?, like `{"x":"8/11/2009","y":0.026572007}`

Comment: Math.max(...array.map(o => o.y))        <3 thx to atom code formatter

Comment: But what if there are two object with the same value on the array? `{"x":"8/11/2009","y":0.026572007}, {"x":"10/11/2009", "y": 0.026572007}`. I mean the find would stop to the first occurence but what for the Math.min?

Comment: Wouldn't this iterate over all objects twice? Reduce would avoid that and give you more flexibility to return either object or value.  See reduce answer (by someone else) below.  Even without reduce, writing a quick function that stored current value in a local variable and iterated once and replaced value if necessary would work better (what reduce does basically)

Comment: a more concise snippet to get the max value: `Math.max(...array.map(o => o.y))`

Comment: @tobyodavies, thanks a lot your answer!! Its so simple and very good!! Can you put the ES6 solution too like @Amnom said please? (I had just done this too haha) `Math.max( ...array.map(o=>o.y) )`

Comment: if we use this with react native the app might get crashed if there is large amount of data

Comment: This method is not advisable, it is better to use reduce. With a large array, apply will be calling max with a large number of arguments, which can cause stack overflow. Refer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809656/how-to-avoid-stack-overflow-when-applying-max-to-a-large-array-in-javascript/30809791

Comment: @SamWatkins 's comment should be added to the answer!

Answer (score 575):

### Find the object whose property "Y" has the greatest value in an array of objects

One way would be to use Array reduce..

```
const max = data.reduce(function(prev, current) {
    return (prev && prev.y > current.y) ? prev : current
}) //returns object
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce
http://caniuse.com/#search=reduce (IE9 and above)

If you don't need to support IE (only Edge), or can use a pre-compiler such as Babel you could use the more terse syntax.

```
const max = data.reduce((prev, current) => (prev && prev.y > current.y) ? prev : current)
```

Comment: This is a good answer, however, you would like to pass an initial value or you would get an error in case the data array is empty. i.e. for an autoincrement index of objects.

`const max = data.reduce((prev, current) => (prev.y > current.y) ? prev : current, 1)`

Comment: You raise a good point, I would probably choose `null` over 1.

Comment: Note that this returns the object that had the max value not the max value from the object. This may or may not be what you want. In my case it was what I wanted. +1

Comment: Excellent answer!
At first, I hesitated due to the reduce, but we're gonna need to iterate anyway, so why not?

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer, because it's unsafe to call apply with a large array, it can cause stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809656/how-to-avoid-stack-overflow-when-applying-max-to-a-large-array-in-javascript/30809791

Comment: @AndyPolhill if you pass `null` instead of `1` as an initial value, then you get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of null`

Comment: Also, make sure the data type is a number and not a string. Otherwise you could get mixed results. Use `parseInt()` where appropriate.

Comment: if some object doesn't have a your comparing property that would be a problem.

Comment: This is the answer to the actual question in the title which says the max _attribute_ which could be of any type.   Granted the example is numbers.   I also really like that this returns the object rather than the value.  Very useful.

Comment: I've updated the answer to guard against "prev" being null. This allows you to call reduce with a null initial value.

Comment: @RobJacobson what aobut missing or string props?

Answer (score 259):

clean and simple ES6 (Babel)

```
const maxValueOfY = Math.max(...arrayToSearchIn.map(o => o.y), 0);
```

The second parameter should ensure a default value if `arrayToSearchIn` is empty.

Comment: also it's good to know that it returns `-Infinity` (a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value) for an empty array

Comment: This is supported in most modern browsers without Babel now.

Comment: as it returns `-Infinity` for an empty array, you can pass an **initial value**
`Math.max(...state.allProjects.map(o => o.id), 1);`

Comment: to handle case for minus values change `0` to `arrayToSearchIn[0].y`. Time complexity comparision: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53654364/860099

Comment: how to get the object here ?

Comment: This method also causes stack overflow for a large array.

Answer (score 171):

Comparison of three **ONELINERS** which handle minus numbers case (input in `a` array):

```
var maxA = a.reduce((a,b)=>a.y>b.y?a:b).y; // 30 chars time complexity:  O(n)

var maxB = a.sort((a,b)=>b.y-a.y)[0].y;    // 27 chars time complexity:  O(nlogn)
           
var maxC = Math.max(...a.map(o=>o.y));     // 26 chars time complexity: >O(2n)
```

[Editable example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/jtzb67ph/). Ideas from: [maxA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34087850/860099), [maxB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48185613/860099) and [maxC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39461900/860099) (side effect of maxB is that array `a` is changed because `sort` is in-place).

```js
var a = [
  {"x":"8/11/2009","y":0.026572007},{"x":"8/12/2009","y":0.025057454},    
  {"x":"8/14/2009","y":0.031004457},{"x":"8/13/2009","y":0.024530916}
]

var maxA = a.reduce((a,b)=>a.y>b.y?a:b).y;
var maxC = Math.max(...a.map(o=>o.y));
var maxB = a.sort((a,b)=>b.y-a.y)[0].y;

document.body.innerHTML=`<pre>maxA: ${maxA}\nmaxB: ${maxB}\nmaxC: ${maxC}</pre>`;
```

For bigger arrays the `Math.max...` will throw exception: *Maximum call stack size exceeded* (Chrome 76.0.3809, Safari 12.1.2, date 2019-09-13)

```js
let a = Array(400*400).fill({"x": "8/11/2009", "y": 0.026572007 }); 

// Exception: Maximum call stack size exceeded

try {
  let max1= Math.max.apply(Math, a.map(o => o.y));
} catch(e) { console.error('Math.max.apply:', e.message) }

try {
  let max2= Math.max(...a.map(o=>o.y));
} catch(e) { console.error('Math.max-map:', e.message) }
```

[Benchmark for the 4 element array](https://jsbench.github.io/#f8f9aa345ca545ea248aa2dc6f7df6c1)

Comment: one thing to point out is option B makes it much easier to get the whole object with the max `y` value by leaving off the `.y` at the end.

Comment: Im not sure to understand why `maxA`'s Math.max() has a second parameter? It should work with only `var maxA = Math.max(...a.map(o=>o.y));`, wouldn't it?

Comment: For those curious about the difference (if any) between O(n) and O(2n) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777714/which-algorithm-is-faster-on-or-o2n

Comment: @jHova - I not use strict big O notation - this is more "practical / intuitive" notation and meaning is following:  the number of operations in O(2n) is twice as high as in O(n) (I'm not going to define it precisely)

Comment: With my lack of math expertise, I just wanted to know which is faster without having to edit the code above with timers and sample runs. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/25899325/2578125, best bet is O(n), though actual usage could vary.

Answer (score 33):

I'd like to explain the [terse accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4020842/2038264) step-by-step:

```js
var objects = [{ x: 3 }, { x: 1 }, { x: 2 }];

// array.map lets you extract an array of attribute values
var xValues = objects.map(function(o) { return o.x; });
// es6
xValues = Array.from(objects, o => o.x);

// function.apply lets you expand an array argument as individual arguments
// So the following is equivalent to Math.max(3, 1, 2)
// The first argument is "this" but since Math.max doesn't need it, null is fine
var xMax = Math.max.apply(null, xValues);
// es6
xMax = Math.max(...xValues);

// Finally, to find the object that has the maximum x value (note that result is array):
var maxXObjects = objects.filter(function(o) { return o.x === xMax; });

// Altogether
xMax = Math.max.apply(null, objects.map(function(o) { return o.x; }));
var maxXObject = objects.filter(function(o) { return o.x === xMax; })[0];
// es6
xMax = Math.max(...Array.from(objects, o => o.x));
maxXObject = objects.find(o => o.x === xMax);


document.write('<p>objects: ' + JSON.stringify(objects) + '</p>');
document.write('<p>xValues: ' + JSON.stringify(xValues) + '</p>');
document.write('<p>xMax: ' + JSON.stringify(xMax) + '</p>');
document.write('<p>maxXObjects: ' + JSON.stringify(maxXObjects) + '</p>');
document.write('<p>maxXObject: ' + JSON.stringify(maxXObject) + '</p>');
```

Further information:

- [`Math.max.apply()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21255138/2038264)
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Great explanation! It might be a bit easier to read if it wasn't in code comments, but still - great work

Answer (score 23):

Well, first you should parse the JSON string, so that you can easily access it's members:

```
var arr = $.parseJSON(str);
```

Use the `map` method to extract the values:

```
arr = $.map(arr, function(o){ return o.y; });
```

Then you can use the array in the `max` method:

```
var highest = Math.max.apply(this,arr);
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
var highest = Math.max.apply(this,$.map($.parseJSON(str), function(o){ return o.y; }));
```

Comment: It's not tagged with `jQuery`

Answer (score 17):

Here is the shortest solution (One Liner) **ES6**:

```
Math.max(...values.map(o => o.y));
```

Comment: again, this is unsafe for large arrays as it will cause a stack overflow crash

Answer (score 15):

if you (or, someone here) are free to use `lodash` utility library, it has a **[maxBy](https://lodash.com/docs/#maxBy)** function which would be very handy in your case.

hence you can use as such:

```
_.maxBy(jsonSlice, 'y');
```

Answer (score 10):

Or a simple sort! Keeping it real :)

```
array.sort((a,b)=>a.y<b.y)[0].y
```

Comment: Nice idea +1 (shortest code), but there is small bug - change `a.y<a.y` to `b.y-a.y`. Time complexity comparison here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53654364/860099

Comment: Finding the max is O(n). This is O(nlogn). Writing simple code is good as long as efficiency is not sacrificed.

Comment: @Wildhammer - actually [Micro-optimisation is worth it when you have evidence that you're optimising a bottleneck.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3471000/860099). In most cases, the simple code is better choice than high-efficient code.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Both array comparisons in that article have the same time complexity the difference is in their coefficient. For instance, one takes n time units to find the solution while the other one is 7n. In time complexity theory, both of these are O(n). What we are talking about in the problem of finding max is the comparison of O(n) with O(n logn). Now if you can guarantee n doesn't exceed 10 then you can use your solution otherwise O(n) algorithm is always the winner and performance(user experience) is always prior to developer experience(ask industry people, they tell you that!).

Comment: @Wildhammer nope - even if your array have n=10000 elements user will not see difference - proof [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/xg1th6c5/). Performance optimisation is good only for app bottleneck (eg. you need to process large arrays) - but in most case a performance-focus is wrong approach and time(=money) wasting. This is well known code approach mistake - read more: "micro-optimisation"

Answer (score 9):

Using one function find the max obj.value return obj

```
 let List= [{votes:4},{votes:8},{votes:7}]


let objMax = List.reduce((max, curren) => max.votes > curren.votes ? max : curren);

console.log(objMax)
```

Or using two functions return max value

```
  Math.max(...List.map(el => el.votes)))
```

Comment: This answer is far from what is being questioning here. This will return the object, not the value.

Answer (score 8):

Each array and get max value with Math.

```
data.reduce((max, b) => Math.max(max, b.costo), data[0].costo);
```

Comment: +1 but use **y**: `data.reduce((max, point) => Math.max(max, point.y), data[0].y);` Many of the other answers create unnecessary temporary arrays or do expensive sorting. Using  **reduce()** plus **Math.max()** is memory and CPU efficient, and it's more readable.

Comment: As mentioned above, can replace initial value with -Infinity.

Answer (score 3):

It returns the object simplified @andy polhill answare

```js
var data = [{
    y: 90
  },
  {
    y: 9
  },
  {
    y: 8
  }
]


const max = data.reduce((prev, current) => ((prev.y > current.y) ?
  prev : current), 0) //returns object
console.log(max)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var max = 0;                
jQuery.map(arr, function (obj) {
  if (obj.attr > max)
    max = obj.attr;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

ES6 solution

`Math.max(...array.map(function(o){return o.y;}))`

For more details see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Answer (score 1):

```
// Here is very simple way to go:

// Your DataSet.

let numberArray = [
  {
    "x": "8/11/2009",
    "y": 0.026572007
  },
  {
    "x": "8/12/2009",
    "y": 0.025057454
  },
  {
    "x": "8/13/2009",
    "y": 0.024530916
  },
  {
    "x": "8/14/2009",
    "y": 0.031004457
  }
]

// 1. First create Array, containing all the value of Y
let result = numberArray.map((y) => y)
console.log(result) // >> [0.026572007,0.025057454,0.024530916,0.031004457]

// 2.
let maxValue = Math.max.apply(null, result)
console.log(maxValue) // >> 0.031004457
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'min',
{
    value: function(f)
    {
        f = f || (v => v);
        return this.reduce((a, b) => (f(a) < f(b)) ? a : b);
    }
});

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'max',
{
    value: function(f)
    {
        f = f || (v => v);
        return this.reduce((a, b) => (f(a) > f(b)) ? a : b);
    }
});

console.log([1,2,3].max());
console.log([1,2,3].max(x => x*(4-x)));
console.log([1,2,3].min());
console.log([1,2,3].min(x => x*(4-x)));
```

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation for accepted answer and a more generalized way

If someone's here to find the max value among all such keys (a generalized way):

```js
const temp1 = [
    {
        "name": "Month 8 . Week 1",
        "CATEGORY, Id 0": null,
        "CATEGORY, Id 1": 30.666666666666668,
        "CATEGORY, Id 2": 17.333333333333332,
        "CATEGORY, Id 3": 12.333333333333334,
        "TASK, Id 1": 30.666666666666668,
        "TASK, Id 2": 12.333333333333334,
        "TASK, Id 3": null,
        "TASK, Id 4": 5,
        "TASK, Id 5": null,
        "TASK, Id 6": null,
        "TASK, Id 7": null,
        "TASK, Id 8": null,
        "TASK, Id 9": null,
        "TASK, Id 10": null,
        "TASK, Id 12": null,
        "TASK, Id 14": null,
        "TASK, Id 16": null,
        "TASK, Id 17": null,
        "TASK, Id 26": 12.333333333333334
    },
    {
        "name": "Month 8 . Week 2",
        "CATEGORY, Id 0": 38,
        "CATEGORY, Id 1": null,
        "CATEGORY, Id 2": 12,
        "CATEGORY, Id 3": null,
        "TASK, Id 1": null,
        "TASK, Id 2": 15,
        "TASK, Id 3": null,
        "TASK, Id 4": null,
        "TASK, Id 5": null,
        "TASK, Id 6": 5,
        "TASK, Id 7": 5,
        "TASK, Id 8": 5,
        "TASK, Id 9": 5,
        "TASK, Id 10": null,
        "TASK, Id 12": null,
        "TASK, Id 14": null,
        "TASK, Id 16": null,
        "TASK, Id 17": null,
        "TASK, Id 26": 15
    },
    {
        "name": "Month 8 . Week 3",
        "CATEGORY, Id 0": 7,
        "CATEGORY, Id 1": 12.333333333333334,
        "CATEGORY, Id 2": null,
        "CATEGORY, Id 3": null,
        "TASK, Id 1": null,
        "TASK, Id 2": null,
        "TASK, Id 3": 12.333333333333334,
        "TASK, Id 4": null,
        "TASK, Id 5": null,
        "TASK, Id 6": null,
        "TASK, Id 7": null,
        "TASK, Id 8": null,
        "TASK, Id 9": null,
        "TASK, Id 10": null,
        "TASK, Id 12": null,
        "TASK, Id 14": 7,
        "TASK, Id 16": null,
        "TASK, Id 17": null,
        "TASK, Id 26": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Month 8 . Week 4",
        "CATEGORY, Id 0": null,
        "CATEGORY, Id 1": null,
        "CATEGORY, Id 2": 10,
        "CATEGORY, Id 3": 5,
        "TASK, Id 1": null,
        "TASK, Id 2": null,
        "TASK, Id 3": null,
        "TASK, Id 4": null,
        "TASK, Id 5": 5,
        "TASK, Id 6": null,
        "TASK, Id 7": null,
        "TASK, Id 8": null,
        "TASK, Id 9": null,
        "TASK, Id 10": 5,
        "TASK, Id 12": 5,
        "TASK, Id 14": null,
        "TASK, Id 16": null,
        "TASK, Id 17": null,
        "TASK, Id 26": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Month 8 . Week 5",
        "CATEGORY, Id 0": 5,
        "CATEGORY, Id 1": null,
        "CATEGORY, Id 2": 7,
        "CATEGORY, Id 3": null,
        "TASK, Id 1": null,
        "TASK, Id 2": null,
        "TASK, Id 3": null,
        "TASK, Id 4": null,
        "TASK, Id 5": null,
        "TASK, Id 6": null,
        "TASK, Id 7": null,
        "TASK, Id 8": null,
        "TASK, Id 9": null,
        "TASK, Id 10": null,
        "TASK, Id 12": null,
        "TASK, Id 14": null,
        "TASK, Id 16": 7,
        "TASK, Id 17": 5,
        "TASK, Id 26": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Month 9 . Week 1",
        "CATEGORY, Id 0": 13.333333333333334,
        "CATEGORY, Id 1": 13.333333333333334,
        "CATEGORY, Id 3": null,
        "TASK, Id 11": null,
        "TASK, Id 14": 6.333333333333333,
        "TASK, Id 17": null,
        "TASK, Id 18": 7,
        "TASK, Id 19": null,
        "TASK, Id 20": null,
        "TASK, Id 26": 13.333333333333334
    },
    {
        "name": "Month 9 . Week 2",
        "CATEGORY, Id 0": null,
        "CATEGORY, Id 1": null,
        "CATEGORY, Id 3": 13.333333333333334,
        "TASK, Id 11": 5,
        "TASK, Id 14": null,
        "TASK, Id 17": 8.333333333333334,
        "TASK, Id 18": null,
        "TASK, Id 19": null,
        "TASK, Id 20": null,
        "TASK, Id 26": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Month 9 . Week 3",
        "CATEGORY, Id 0": null,
        "CATEGORY, Id 1": 14,
        "CATEGORY, Id 3": null,
        "TASK, Id 11": null,
        "TASK, Id 14": null,
        "TASK, Id 17": null,
        "TASK, Id 18": null,
        "TASK, Id 19": 7,
        "TASK, Id 20": 7,
        "TASK, Id 26": null
    }
]

console.log(Math.max(...[].concat([], ...temp1.map(i => Object.values(i))).filter(v => typeof v === 'number')))
```

one thing to note that `Math.max(1, 2, 3)` returns `3`.
So does `Math.max(...[1, 2, 3])`, since [Spread syntax can be used when all elements from an object or array need to be included in a list of some kind.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#description)

We will take advantage of this!

Let's assume an array which looks like:

```
var a = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {foo: 12, bar: 141}]
```

And the goal is to find the max (among any attribute), (here it is `bar`(141))

so to use `Math.max()` we need values in one array (so we can do `...arr`)

First let's just separate all the numbers
We can each that each item of the array `a` is an object.
While iterating through each of them, [`Object.values(item)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) will give us all the values of that item in an array form, and we can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to generate a new array with only values

So,

```
var p = a.map(item => Object.values(item)) // [ [1, 2], [12, 141] ]
```

Also,using [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat),

[`[].concat([], ...arr)`, or just `[].concat(...arr)` on arr, `[ [1, 2], [12, 141] ]` flattens it to `[1, 2, 12, 141]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34980419/11667949)

So,

```
var f = [].concat(...p) // [1, 2, 12, 141]
```

since we have now an array of just numbers we do Math.max(...f):

```
var m = Math.max(...f) // 141
```

Answer (score 1):

This typescript function can be called to search for the largest value that can exist in a field of the objects of an array:

```
function getHighestField(objArray: any[], fieldName: string) {
  return Number(
    Math.max.apply(
      Math,
      objArray?.map(o => o[fieldName] || 0),
    ) || 0,
  );
}
```

---

With this values as an example:

```
const scoreBoard = [
  { name: 'player1', score: 4 },
  { name: 'player2', score: 9 },
  { name: 'player3', score: 7 }
]
```

You can call the function something this way:

```
const myHighestVariable = `This is the highest: ${getHighestField(scoreBoard, "score")}`;
```

The result will be something like this:

```
console.log(myHighestVariable);
```

> This is the highest: 9

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple

```
     const array1 = [
  {id: 1, val: 60},
  {id: 2, val: 2},
  {id: 3, val: 89},
  {id: 4, val: 78}
];
const array2 = [1,6,8,79,45,21,65,85,32,654];
const max = array1.reduce((acc, item) => acc = acc > item.val ? acc : item.val, 0);
const max2 = array2.reduce((acc, item) => acc = acc > item ? acc : item, 0);

console.log(max);
console.log(max2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getMaxFromListByField = (list, field) => { 
    return list[list.map(it => it[field]).indexOf(Math.max(...list.map(it => it[field])))] 
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

carefull on null and empty and property not in array and empty array

```
if ((value && value.length > 0)) {
  var maxObj = (value && value.length > 0) value.reduce(function (prev, current) {
    return ((parseInt(prev["y"]) || 0) > (parseInt(current["y"]) || 0)) ? prev : current
  })
}
{
  // else logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a grain of salt on Andy's answer:
One can use a filter before reducing to avoid passing empty arrays, which could mess everything.

```
const max = data
.filter(item=>item.id != undefined) // --> here
.reduce(function(prev, current) {return (prev.y > current.y) ? prev : current
    }) //returns object
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only the max "y",

```
const maxY = data.reduce((y, current) => (y == undefined || current.y > y) ? current.y : y, undefined)
```

.