# find max date out of three datetime variables

Tags: javascript

I have question regarding `date comparison in javascript`.
I want to `find max date out of three datetime variables`.

**Like,** i can find max date in `c# linq` using following short way

```
maxDate= new[] {p1.Date, p2.Date, p3.Date}.Max();
```

Does `javascript` has such nice way to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143399/min-max-of-dates-in-an-array

Comment: People always seem to forget that Dates are actually "cool" Numbers in Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `Math.max`, like this:

```
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date();
var d3 = new Date();

var max = Math.max(d1, d2, d3);

// Will give you the max Date
console.log(new Date(max));
```

Comment: `.getTime()` is not needed... `var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date();
var d3 = new Date();
var max = Math.max(d1, d2, d3);
console.log(max);`

Comment: This seems very nice solution. let me try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `sort` method of js array to find min & max date

```
/* In ascending order*/
        function sortDates(a, b)
    {
        return a.getTime() - b.getTime();
    }  



/* in descending order.max & min value will be different
    function sortDates(a, b)
    {
        return b.getTime() - b.getTime();
    } */

var dates = [];

dates.push(new Date("03/18/2016"))
dates.push(new Date("03/18/2015"))
dates.push(new Date("03/18/2017"))
dates.push(new Date("03/18/2018"))

var sortedArray  = dates.sort(sortDates);
var minDate = sortedArray [0];
var maxDate = sortedArray [sortedArray .length-1];
console.log(minDate , maxDate);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/dhL7wzxq/1/)