# Get most current data from Array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a SP2010 list which contains a column with dates. (Date created).

I pull these using Spservices which comes in the following format:`YYYY.MM.DD 00:00`.

In the main function which reads the list I split the date so all that remains is `YYYY.MM.DD`.

```js
dateAdded = ($(this).attr("ows_DatumActualiteit")).split(" ")[0];
```

The dates are then pushed in to an array for later filtering.

```
function selectMostRecentAct(datesIn){
    var dateArray = [];
    dateArray.push(datesIn);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(dateArray[i]); //spits out all the dates in the array.
        
};
```

I want to select the most recent date in this array. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you should post a snippet with the data to test

Comment: You might either add a tag or explain what `SP2010`/`Spservices` are.

Answer (score 1):

This question seems similar to yours:
[What is the elegant way to get the latest date from array of objects in client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577205/what-is-the-elegant-way-to-get-the-latest-date-from-array-of-objects-in-client-s)

An alternative would be to loop through the whole array and compare the dates. As far as I know, you can use the <, >, == operators with dates.

```
dateArray.forEach((e) => {
    if (e > latestDate)
        latestDate = e;
});
console.log('Latest date is: ' + latestDate);
```

Comment: Most people forget that timestrings can be easily sorted without complicated Date conversion. +1 for providing the easiest and probably fastest answer, however you should definetly declare `latestDate` ...

Comment: Thanks and yes exactly, you should define the latestDate variable outside the loop (and set it to the earliest possible date?)

Comment: I think Jonas was suggesting that you should edit the answer to include that initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort the values then take the first element.

I'm assuming the format of your dates, but `new Date` is very lenient and should accept most reasonable inputs.

```js
const dates = [
  "2018-03-01T10:30:12.000Z",
  "2018-03-01T12:11:49.000Z",
  "2018-03-12T15:54:49.000Z",
  "2018-03-09T19:12:49.000Z",
  "2018-03-03T01:41:49.000Z",
];

const selectMostRecent = dates =>
  dates.sort((a, b) => new Date(b) - new Date(a))[0];

console.log(selectMostRecent(dates));
```

Sort wants a comparison function that returns a value, either positive, negative or zero. When you perform arithmetic on a date value it is converted to epoch time (e.g. 1522096404277, milliseconds since 01/01/1970), and then subtracting these gives us the signed value we desire.

For example,
`2018-03-09T19:12:49.000Z` returns `1520622769000`
`2018-03-03T01:41:49.000Z` returns `1520041309000`

And when we do `2018-03-09T19:12:49.000Z - 2018-03-03T01:41:49.000Z` (but those are coerced to numbers as described above) we get `581460000`, meaning that the first date is sorted above the latter one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
dateArray
   .map(d => new Date(d.replace(/\./g, "-"))) // ISO format
   .sort((a, b) => b - a) // Newest to oldest, probably
   [0] // First!
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses a reusable function for `max`; it should work for any values that you can compare with `>`.  Note that it requires you to set a minimum value.  For strings, `""` (the empty string) seems appropriate.  For numbers, you could use `-Infinity`, although that case is already covered by `Math.max`.  For actual dates (not these dates formatted as strings), you can choose any date that would be well before any conceivable values, perhaps something like `new Date(-1e15)`.

```js
const max = (min) => vals => vals.reduce((curr, val) => val > curr ? val : curr, min)
const maxDate = max('')

console.log(
  maxDate(['2014.07.23', '2014.08.29', '2007.03.25', '2017.09.30', '2008.02.29'])
)
```