# Search within array of objects the latest matching record

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I have list of object from my api, I want to display the latest value,

Here's my object.
[image]

Here's how I got my location 3.

```
records.forEach((record) => {
      if (record.location == locationId) {
        result.push(record);
  }});
```

But now I want to get the latest record from it.

Any help would be very thankful!

Comment: Sort the array by timestamp, then pick the first element?

Comment: I was unable to sort it, not sure why @ChrisG

Comment: See the duplicate questions and especially have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57731226/906113).

Answer (score 2):

Sorting is a relatively ***expensive*** operation (O(n log n) time complexity).

Instead, you may traverse your source array with `Array.prototype.reduce()` just once (O(n) time algorithm) to find out the *latest* record that corresponds to desired `location`:

```js
const src = Array.from(
  {length: 15},
  (_,i) => ({location: 0|i/3, timestamp: new Date(2020,5,i+1).toLocaleString('uk-UA')})
),

      getLatestForLocation = (log, locationId) =>
        log.reduce((r, item) => {
          if(locationId != item.location) return r
          if(!r.timestamp || r.timestamp < item.timestamp)
            r = item
          return r
        }, {})

console.log(src)
console.log(`latest record for location id 2: `, getLatestForLocation(src,2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You filter then sort then take the first element:

```js
var records = [
  {value: '1', location: '3', timestamp: '2020-04-28 10:12'},
  {value: '2', location: '2', timestamp: '2020-04-28 00:24'},
  {value: '3', location: '3', timestamp: '2020-04-28 07:37'},
  {value: '4', location: '3', timestamp: '2020-04-28 14:27'},
  {value: '5', location: '3', timestamp: '2020-04-28 23:28'},
  {value: '6', location: '1', timestamp: '2020-04-28 10:13'}
]

console.log(records.filter(x => x.location == 3).sort((a,b)=> a.timestamp < b.timestamp ? 1 : -1)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the records:

```js
records.sort(({ timestamp: a }, { timestamp: b }) => a > b ? -1 : 1);
```

Now `records[0]` is the latest one.

Comment: The "location" filter is not taken into account and you lose in efficiency because of the Date. Seeing the format, you can just sort alphabetically ;)

Comment: Technically I don't think you need to convert to a Date object, since ISO format dates are alphabetically comparable.

Answer (score 0):

Your routine will create a `result` array that looks something like this:

```
const result = [                                         
  { value: '15', location: '3', timestamp: '2020-06-11 19:48:28' },
  { value: '16', location: '3', timestamp: '2020-06-10 19:48:28' },
  { value: '14', location: '3', timestamp: '2020-06-19 19:48:28' } 
];
```

Then you can simply do:

```
const latest = result.sort((a,b) => a.timestamp < b.timestamp)[0];
```