# Find min/max of two dates (typed)

Tags: typescript, date, max, min

I want a strongly typed code. When I apply solutions from a similar question - [Min/Max of dates in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7143399/1429387) - I get error

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```

my code

```
  const min: Date = Math.min(begin as Date, (end || defaultDate) as Date);
  const max: Date = Math.max(begin as Date, (end || defaultDate) as Date);
```

`begin as Date` part is underlined.

What's the correct way of finding min/max dates in Typescript?

Comment: `Math.min()` and `Math.max()` return a number. You can't make them return a Date object with typings.

Comment: @GuyIncognito I see, I understand. But what's the correct way? `const min: Date = new Date(Math.min(begin.getDate(), (end || hover).getDate()))` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare dates like so in typescript:

```js
const begin: Date = new Date();
const end: Date = new Date();

const min: Date = begin < end ? begin : end;
const max: Date = begin > end ? begin : end;
```

The problem you were having is that `Math.min` returns a number.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have an array, you will map the date part by taking its `getTime()`, then pass it to `Math.min` and when you get it back, again convert it to date.

```js
const result:number[] = array.map((item)=>new Date(item.date).getTime());
console.log(new Date(Math.min(...result)));
```

Answer (score 0):

*Thank you @OliverRadini for sample code!*

My own solution, taking into account possibly nullable dates:

```
const begin: Date | null | undefined = // ...
const end: Date | null | undefined = // ...
const defaultDate: Date = new Date();

let min: Date;
let max: Date;
if (!begin || !end) {
  min = (begin || end || defaultDate);
  max = (begin || end || defaultDate);
} else if (begin > end) {
  min = end;
  max = begin;
} else {
  min = begin;
  max = end;
}
```