# check min date and max date using javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, datetime-format

Having to dates like this
'2022-04-30' & '2022-05-30'

using javascript how can evaluate which dates is lower ?
I tried to convert them to milliseconds but with this format date I dont know how

example

if('2022-04-30' < '2022-05-30')
{

// true
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Min/Max of dates in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143399/min-max-of-dates-in-an-array)

Comment: `if ('2022-04-30' < '2022-05-30')` is fine, ISO 8601 format date strings are designed to compare correctly as strings. If you *really* want to convert to number (millisecond offset), then `Date.parse('2022-04-30') < date.parse('2022-05-30')` works too, provided the strings are in a format supported by ECMA-262 (which the OP strings are). :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: As pointed out by [@RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) the dates are in the ISO format so there is no need for dates at all:

```js
if ('2022-04-30' < '2022-05-30')
  console.log('true')
```

*However* this does not work with other date formats, for example:

```js
if ('30-04-2022' < '30-05-2020')
  console.log('returns true, but is incorrect')
  
if (new Date('30-04-2022') < new Date('30-05-2020'))
  console.log('returns false')
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER:
You are trying to compare strings not dates. Try this:

```js
const date1 = new Date('2022-04-30');
const date2 = new Date('2022-05-30');

if (date1 < date2) {
  console.log('true');
}
```

Or shorter:

```js
if (new Date('2022-04-30') < new Date('2022-05-30'))
  console.log('true');
```

Comment: "*You are trying to compare strings not dates*" is not a problem. ISO 8601 dates compare as strings, so no need for Dates at all. `'2022-04-30' < '2022-05-30'` returns *true*, as it should.