# Finding smallest value in a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have an array like the following:

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray[0] = {ValueA: 10, ValueB:900};
myArray[1] = {ValueA: 50, ValueB:190};
```

How would I select the element that has the smallest value for `ValueA`?

I've used the following to get the max of arrays of numbers before:

```
var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, myArray);
```

but i'm not sure how this method could be used to find the max/min of an array of objects.  Suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020796/finding-max-value-in-multidimensional-json-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could sort the array using a custom function then get the first and last members, e.g.

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {return a.ValueA - b.ValueA;});
```

Smallest:

```
myArray[0].ValueA;
```

Biggest:

```
myArray[myArray.length - 1].ValueA;
```

If you don't want to modify the order of your array, copy it first (the objects wont be copied, they'll just be referenced).

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray[0] = {ValueA: 10, ValueB:900};
myArray[1] = {ValueA: 50, ValueB:190};
myArray[2] = {ValueA: 25, ValueB:160};
myArray[3] = {ValueA: 5, ValueB:10};

var copy = myArray.slice();
alert(copy.length);

copy.sort(function(a, b) {return a.ValueA - b.ValueA;});

alert(copy[0].ValueA); // 5
alert(copy[copy.length - 1].ValueA); // 50
```

Comment: Nice -- what I would do. While this problem is solvable in `O(n)` bounds, `O(n lg n)` is generally quite sufficient (computer time is far cheaper than my development time :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.min.apply(Math,myArray.map(function(x){return x.ValueA;}));
```

Comment: This does not work right away, but is an interesting solution. It would be great if you could expand on this a little more and maybe test it or provide a JSFiddle

Comment: The OP is not looking for the minimum *value*, but rather the object(s) which *have* that minimum value.