# Is n or nlog(n) better than constant or logarithmic time?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

In the Princeton tutorial on Coursera the lecturer explains the common order-of-growth functions that are encountered. He says that linear and linearithmic running times are "what we strive" for and his reasoning was that as the input size increases so too does the running time. I think this is where he made a mistake because I have previously heard him refer to a linear order-of-growth as unsatisfactory for an efficient algorithm.

While he was speaking he also showed a chart that plotted the different running times - constant and logarithmic running times looked to be more efficient. So was this a mistake or is this true?

Comment: There are few algorithms that are O(log n) or O(1) total running time. O(n) time over n elements is still quite good.

Comment: No, but a little-o(n) time algorithm can't examine the entirety of the input.

Comment: All can be O(n) with [Quantum sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort#Related_algorithms)  ;-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're missing the broader context in which those statements must have been made. Different kinds of problems have different demands, and often even have theoretical lower bounds on how much work is *absolutely necessary* to solve them, no matter the means.

For operations like sorting or scanning every element of a simple collection, you can make a hard lower bound of the number of elements in the collection for those operations, because the output depends on every element of the input. [1] Thus, O(n) or O(n*log(n)) are the best one can do.

For other kinds of operations, like accessing a single element of a hash table or linked list, or searching in a sorted set, the algorithm needn't examine all of the input. In those settings, an O(n) operation would be dreadfully slow.

[1] Others will note that sorting by comparisons also has an n*log(n) lower bound, from information-theoretic arguments. There are non-comparison based sorting algorithms that can beat this, for some types of input.

Answer (score 69):

It is a mistake when taken in the context that O(n) and O(n log n) functions have better complexity than O(1) and O(log n) functions. When looking typical cases of complexity in big O notation:

O(1) < O(log n) < O(n) < O(n log n) < O(n^2)

Notice that this doesn't necessarily mean that they will always be better performance-wise - we could have an O(1) function that takes a long time to execute even though its complexity is unaffected by element count. Such a function would look better in big O notation than an O(log n) function, but could actually perform worse in practice.

Generally speaking: a function with lower complexity (in big O notation) will outperform a function with greater complexity (in big O notation) *when n is sufficiently high*.

Comment: Isn't O(n log n) < O(n) ? Fox example n = 5 then 5*log5 = 3.49 which is obviously smaller than 5.

Comment: @Ahtisham for small values of n, but with big-O we're always looking for eventual trends. `1< log n` when n is sufficiently high, thus `n < n log n` is as well.

Comment: Oh! Got you ☺️ like 15log(15) = 17.64 which definitely greater than 15. ☺️. +1 vote ☺️

Comment: when we say log(n) do we mean log to the base 2 or 10 ?

Comment: @Ahtisham generally with computers you can assume base 2, however converting between logs involves multiplying by a constant. Constants are removed by big-O, so when you see `O(log n)` it doesn't really matter what the base is!

Comment: You can see that `n log n > n` when you plot both of them together: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tumnigwr9z

Comment: Because people flock to this answer for some reason, an addendum: the example of `O(n log n) < O(n)` @Ahtisham proposes is _precisely_ why I say a function can perform worse in practice. If - in our application - `n` is never large enough to escape that part of the curve where  `O(n log n) < O(n)`, then our choice of an `O(n)` algorithm wouldn't be optimal! My point is that complexity is a very good heuristic, but choosing an algorithm based on profiling will be better where you need optimal behavior

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, what we strive for is the best we can manage to do. But depending on what we're doing, that might be O(1), O(log log N), O(log N), O(N), O(N log N), O(N<sup>2</sup>), O(N<sup>3</sup>), or (or certain algorithms) perhaps O(N!) or even O(2<sup>N</sup>).

Just for example, when you're dealing with searching in a sorted collection, binary search borders on trivial and gives O(log N) complexity. If the distribution of items in the collection is reasonably predictable, we can typically do even better--around O(log log N). Knowing that, an algorithm that was O(N) or O(N<sup>2</sup>) (for a couple of obvious examples) would probably be pretty disappointing.

On the other hand, sorting is generally quite a bit higher complexity--the "good" algorithms manage O(N log N), and the poorer ones are typically around O(N<sup>2</sup>). Therefore, for sorting an O(N) algorithm is actually very good (in fact, only possible for rather constrained types of inputs), and we can pretty much count on the fact that something like O(log log N) simply isn't possible.

Going even further, we'd be happy to manage a matrix multiplication in only O(N<sup>2</sup>) instead of the usual O(N<sup>3</sup>). We'd be *ecstatic* to get optimum, reproducible answers to the traveling salesman problem or subset sum problem in only O(N<sup>3</sup>), given that optimal solutions to these normally require O(N!).

Answer (score 4):

Algorithms with a sublinear behavior like O(1) or O(Log(N)) are special in that they do not require to look at all elements. In a way this is a fallacy because if there are really N elements, it will take O(N) just to read or compute them.

Sublinear algorithms are often possible after some preprocessing has been performed. Think of binary search in a sorted table, taking O(Log(N)). If the data is initially unsorted, it will cost O(N Log(N)) to sort it first. The cost of sorting can be balanced if you perform many searches, say K, on the same data set. Indeed, without the sort, the cost of the searches will be O(K N), and with pre-sorting O(N Log(N)+ K Log(N)). You win if K >> Log(N).

This said, when no preprocessing is allowed, O(N) behavior is ideal, and O(N Log(N)) is quite comfortable as well (for a million elements, Lg(N) is only 20). You start screaming with O(N²) and worse.

Comment: > 'You win if K >> Log(N)'. I did some calcs and I think you win if k > n log(n) / (n - log(n)). By algebra, starting from: k*n > n log(n) + k log(n). Also did some spreadsheet analysis to compare the two (K > Log(N) and my formula, and mine seems to hold up). So I edited the above answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes constant time i.e. O(1) is better than linear time O(n) because the former is not depending on the input-size of the problem. The order is O(1) > O (logn) > O (n) > O (nlogn).
Linear or linearthimic time we strive for because going for O(1) might not be realistic as in every sorting algorithm we atleast need a few comparisons which the professor tries to prove with his decison Tree- comparison analysis where he tries to sort three elements a b c and proves a lower bound of nlogn. Check his "Complexity of Sorting" in the Mergesort lecture.

Answer (score 1):

He said those algorithms are what we strive for, which is generally true. Many algorithms cannot possibly be improved better than logarithmic or linear time, and while constant time would be better in a perfect world, it's often unattainable.

Answer (score 1):

constant time is always better because the time (or space) complexity doesn't depend on the problem size... isn't it a great feature? :-)

then we have O(N) and then Nlog(N)

did you know? problems with constant time complexity exist!

e.g.

let A[N] be an array of N integer values, with N > 3. Find and algorithm to tell if the sum of the first three elements is positive or negative.

Comment: @Conduit: can you give an example ? A problem that can be solved in O(1) is inherently Omega(1), and on the opposite it is pretty unnatural to find an O(n) solution for it.

Comment: @conduit We are not talking about the effort to implement the algotirhm but the time complexity of such algorithm

Comment: @YvesDaoust

An O(1) function CAN BE WORSE than an O(log n) function in practice. Consider the C++ map and unordered_map classes. They are pretty much the same in terms of functionality - you look up a stored value with a key value. Insertion complexity is O(log n) on a map and O(1) on an unordered_map - this is because the unordered_map uses a hash table for insertion and lookup. If the hashing function is expensive, though, then the O(1) insert could take more time than the O(n) insert until n is VERY high. Constant time != less time if it is constantly a lot of time ;)

Comment: @Conduit: what you say is the proof you don't understand exactly what big O notation means. Even O(N^2) algorithms can be faster than O(N) algorithms if you use clever programming techniques but that's not the point. It's just a matter of what's the relationship between the input size and the computational time (or space). Big O notation is agnostic of all the implementation details.

Comment: I have a major in mathematics, bud - I understand big O notation. I'm taking issue with the fact that you state that "constant time is **always better** because the time (or space) complexity doesn't depend on the problem size" which is inherently untrue. Big O is naive to the actual number of operations - that statement is wrong.

Comment: If O(1) is 100 in actual complexity and O(n) is 2*n+5 in actual complexity, then when n=3: O(1)->100 and O(n)->11. The O(1) operation will only be better *if n becomes high enough*. Misrepresenting this fact to an asker who is obviously new to the subject promotes bad programming practices.

Comment: @Conduit: this comparison does not make sense, you are comparing algorithms that solve different problems.

Comment: @Conduit: you are talking about two different problems (one solvable in constant time, the other solvabe in linear time) so arguing about which complexity is better doesn't make any sense. I just wanted to say that from a complexity point of view O(1) is better than O(N), not that O(1) algorithms are always faster that O(N) ones. I hope you understand me

Comment: Ahhh, okay - I misinterpreted you as meaning better performance-wise. My point was that we find applications for algorithms with worse complexity because better complexity doesn't necessarily mean better performance... performance is bound to use case. Apologies for the misunderstanding!

Answer (score 1):

What we strive for is **efficiency**, in the sense of designing algorithms with a time (or space) complexity that does not exceed their theoretical lower bound.

For instance, using comparison-based algorithms, you can't find a value in a sorted array faster than Omega(Log(N)), and you cannot sort an array faster than Omega(N Log(N)) - in the worst case.

Thus, binary search O(Log(N)) and Heapsort O(N Log(N)) are efficient algorithms, while linear search O(N) and Bubblesort O(N²) are not.

The lower bound depends on the problem to be solved, not on the algorithm.