# Find the most expensive item in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array as such:

```
let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Chromebook 2",
    type: "computer",
    price: 399.99
  },
 {
    itemName: "Programming 101",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  } 
]
```

I need to create a function that loops through the array and finds the most expensive item and returns the itemName. I am brand new to JS and don't know really the best way to tackle this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the max value of an attribute in an array of objects and return the entire object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895208/finding-the-max-value-of-an-attribute-in-an-array-of-objects-and-return-the-enti) or [ES6 Find the maximum number of an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786855/es6-find-the-maximum-number-of-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method. Check the prices and use `.` to access the max items name.

> From MDN: The `reduce()` method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in single output value.

`?` is called [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (its a short form of `if` and `else`)

More Info on how `reduce` works [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/reduce-f47a7da511a9/)

**Live Demo:**

```js
let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Chromebook 2",
    type: "computer",
    price: 399.99
  },
 {
    itemName: "Programming 101",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  } 
]

let maxItem = items.reduce((max, min) => max.price > min.price ? max : min);

console.log(maxItem.itemName) //Chromebook 2
console.log(maxItem) //Full object
```

Comment: I have never used reduce, could you please explain what "? max : min" I understand the rest

Comment: @AlbertGonzalez min and max is just arg name. you can name it whatever you like. They way it works is its checks loops through the array and checks two object at a time show only where price is higher then the other using the `ternary operator`. Its like checking `if` and `else` to see which is higher in price and its shown only that object from the whole data. I will add most info in the answer.

Comment: extremely helpful, thank you very much! You have answered both my questions thus far superbly!

Comment: @AlbertGonzalez Happy to help always. No worries :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Lodash library, it is very easy and fast to integrate. Lodash "maxBy" can find max value from array. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#maxBy

```js
let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Chromebook 2",
    type: "computer",
    price: 399.99
  },
 {
    itemName: "Programming 101",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  } 
]

console.log(_.maxBy(items, function(o) {
      return o.price;
 }));
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
function getMostExp(items) {
  let mostExp = 0;
  let name;

  items.forEach(item => {
   if(item.price > mostExp) {
     mostExp = item.price;
     name = item.itemName;
   }
  });

  return name;
}
```

UPDATE:

Updated answer to return `itemName` instead of `price`.

Comment: OP is asking for the Item Name, not the Item Price.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array by price, then pop off the last item and get the itemName:

`items.sort((a,b) => a.price - b.price).pop().itemName`

```js
let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Chromebook 2",
    type: "computer",
    price: 399.99
  },
 {
    itemName: "Programming 101",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  } 
]
console.log([...items].sort((a,b) => a.price - b.price).pop().itemName)
```

Comment: Just a minor thing, there is no need to use a `spreader operator` here.

Comment: @KarlL if you don't use a spreader you'll remove the item from the original array, which may not be what they want to do.

Comment: good point. I agree. just in case the OP needs the original data

Comment: @dave why use pop. just sort the arr in rev order and use [0]