# How to set maximum value from json response in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

I am new to AngularJS and I want to set maximum value from JSON response.

**My JSON response :**

```
var json_response = [
  {
    "division": "Development",
    "divisionactualcount": "100",
    "divisiontargetcount": "10"
  },
  {
    "division": "QA",
    "divisionactualcount": "200",
    "divisiontargetcount": "1"
  }
]
```

I want to set maximum value

```
var maxCount = {{maximum value of divisionactualcount}};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020796/finding-the-max-value-of-an-attribute-in-an-array-of-objects

Comment: `Math.max.apply(Math,json_response.map(function(o){return o.divisionactualcount;}))`

Comment: Regarding requests for urgency, [please read this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495).

Answer (score 0):

https://plnkr.co/edit/tNhLmfpjd8xw7HZbvSSJ?p=preview

```
$scope.maxvalue=json_response[0].divisionactualcount;

    for(var i=0;i<(json_response.length)-1;i++){
      if((parseInt(json_response[i].divisionactualcount)) < (parseInt(json_response[i+1].divisionactualcount))&&(parseInt(json_response[i+1].divisionactualcount)) > $scope.maxvalue){
        $scope.maxvalue=json_response[i+1].divisionactualcount;
      }
    }
```

This can be a solution for your question..

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.maxx = 0;
for(var x in json_response){
    if(json_response[x].divisionactualcount > $scope.maxx){
        $scope.maxx = json_response[x].divisionactualcount;
    }
 }
 alert($scope.maxx);
```

`maxx` will give you maximum value from `divisionactualcount`of `json_response` .

Regards.