# angular2, how to return object who have the max value of an attribute in an array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript

i'am working on an angular2 app , i have an array of objects and i want to return the object how has max value of an attribute (in my case the object how have more likes) how to do that in typescript

```js
import {Player} from './player';
export const PlayersData : Player[] = [
{id:1,name:"Marc-andré Ter stegen",number:"1",post:"Goalkeeper",goals:0,assist:0,likes:10,dislike:0,img:"http://s.weltsport.net/bilder/spieler/gross/150720.jpg"},
{id:2,name:"Gerrad Piqué",number:"3",post:"Defender",goals:0,assist:0,likes:10,dislike:0,img:"http://s.weltsport.net/bilder/spieler/gross/27798.jpg"},
{id:3,name:"Ivan Rakitić",number:"4",post:"Midfielder",goals:0,assist:0,likes:7,dislike:0,img:"http://s.weltsport.net/bilder/spieler/gross/35308.jpg"},
{id:4,name:"Sergie Buskquets",number:"5",post:"Midfielder",goals:0,assist:0,likes:10,dislike:0,img:"http://s.weltsport.net/bilder/spieler/gross/124973.jpg"},
{id:5,name:"Denis Suarez",number:"6",post:"Midfielder",goals:20,assist:20,likes:10,dislike:0,img:"http://s.weltsport.net/bilder/spieler/gross/200516.jpg"},
{id:6,name:"Arda Turan",number:"7",post:"Midfielder",goals:0,assist:10,likes:10,dislike:0,img:"http://s.weltsport.net/bilder/spieler/gross/30203.jpg"},
{id:7,name:"Andres Iniesta",number:"8",post:"Midfielder",goals:10,assist:20,likes:0,dislike:0,img:"http://s.weltsport.net/bilder/spieler/gross/5057.jpg"},
{id:8,name:"Luis Suarez",number:"9",post:"Forward",goals:0,assist:0,likes:30,dislike:0,img:"http://s.weltsport.net/bilder/spieler/gross/43635.jpg"},
{id:9,name:"Lionel Messi",number:"10",post:"Forward",goals:0,assist:0,likes:40,dislike:0,img:"http://s.weltsport.net/bilder/spieler/gross/26622.jpg"},
{id:10,name:"Neymar Jr",number:"11",post:"Forward",goals:30,assist:10,likes:30,dislike:0,img:"http://s.weltsport.net/bilder/spieler/gross/142105.jpg"},
{id:11,name:"Javier Mascherano",number:"14",post:"Defender",goals:0,assist:0,likes:10,dislike:0,img:"http://s.weltsport.net/bilder/spieler/gross/22185.jpg"},
{id:12,name:"Jordi Alba",number:"18",post:"Defender",goals:0,assist:0,likes:10,dislike:0,img:"http://s.weltsport.net/bilder/spieler/gross/125417.jpg"},
{id:13,name:"Sergio Roberto",number:"20",post:"Midfielder",goals:0,assist:0,likes:20,dislike:0,img:"http://s.weltsport.net/bilder/spieler/gross/171905.jpg"},
{id:14,name:"Samuel Umtiti",number:"23",post:"Defender",goals:0,assist:0,likes:9,dislike:0,img:"http://s.weltsport.net/bilder/spieler/gross/170711.jpg"}

];
```

this is what i tried in typescript

```js
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  players : Player[] = [];
 bestPlayer:Player;
  constructor(private playerService : PlayerService) { }
 max =0;
 bestPlayer = this.players[0];
  ngOnInit() {
   this.playerService.getPlayers()
   .then(players=> this.players = players);
   for (player of players)
      if (player.likes>max) {
        max => player.likes;
        bestPlayer => player;
      }
  }



}
```

Comment: The same way you would in javascript. What have you tried so far?

Comment: check the edit i added what i tried in typescript

Comment: Your `then` will not complete before the next line under the `getPlayers` call executes. Your `for` loop will always loop over an empty array. Move that all into the `then` statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

As Igor comment, you should read duplicate topic first.
I also give suggest for your other stuck, get object contain max value.
Please read other topic for clear answer [Finding the max value of an attribute in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020796/finding-the-max-value-of-an-attribute-in-an-array-of-objects)

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  players : Player[] = [];
  bestPlayer:Player;

  constructor(private playerService : PlayerService) { }

  max =0;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.playerService.getPlayers()
    .then(players=> {
         this.players = players;
         let maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math,players.map(function(o){return o.likes;}));
         this.bestPlayer = players.filter(function(o) { return o.likes === maxValue; })[0];
     });    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#maxBy). They have a [maxBy function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#maxBy) that parses an array of objects and returns the one with a max value by property.

Example from their site.

```
var objects = [{ 'n': 1 }, { 'n': 2 }];

_.maxBy(objects, function(o) { return o.n; });
// => { 'n': 2 }

// The `_.property` iteratee shorthand.
_.maxBy(objects, 'n');
// => { 'n': 2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution :

```js
bestPlayer:Player;
data:Player[];
max:number =0;
  constructor(private playerService : PlayerService) { }
  ngOnInit() { 
    this.data=this.playerService.getDatas();
    for (var i = 0; i <= this.data.length; i++) {
    if (this.data[i].likes>this.max) {
      this.max=this.data[i].likes;
      this.bestPlayer=this.data[i];
      
     } 
  }
```