# Get array key of subarray with the greatest value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array in javascript with this structure:

```
controllers: Array(2)
    0: Object
        vram: 4095
    1: Object
        vram: 1024
```

This array is generated via [si.graphics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation). There can be more sub-arrays with different values.

I need to somehow return just the index of the controller with the most vram. I've found other stack questions about something similar, but seemingly only with flat arrays, but this array is multi-dimensional.

I haven't tried much to accomplish this because I simply do not know where to start.

How can I get the index of the sub-array with the most vram?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020796/finding-the-max-value-of-an-attribute-in-an-array-of-objects) is not a duplicate because it is focusing on getting the highest value itself, which is pretty trivial and is not what I am/was asking for.

Comment: This is neither an array, nor an object

Comment: @Luca I didn't mean that the structure is how the array is made. Just that it is the current structure of the array, I'm simply showing you the values and how it is set up. I'm not asking whether the array is valid.

Comment: It'd still be best to show the array in a valid format. We can determine the structure of a valid array quite easily.

Comment: So what is the structure then? Could you please add a [mcve] explaining what you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Arrays dont have keys rather indexes. indexes are their keys however.

Comment: @Luca I have done that. It has nothing to do with the structure of the array. I was outlining the values that matter, and showing they are a subarray of an array.

Comment: @Rikin That's probably just the PHP in my brain mixing up wordings.

Comment: Give me a second, going to update the post with the structure from `console.log()`.

Comment: @Rikin Array indices are keys: `Object.keys(['',''])` returns `["0","1"]`

Comment: @Paulpro got it. thanks for clarification. edited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the max value of an attribute in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020796/finding-the-max-value-of-an-attribute-in-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: depending on the use case, I think that you should maybe think of creating a structure similar to a maxHeap.  Im just not sure of the regularity of your use case.

Comment: @Fallenreaper I can't really change the structure, it's a part of a nodejs module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the array by checking the value and with the value of the last max value.

```js
var controllers = [{ vram: 4095 }, { vram: 1024 }],
    maxIndex = controllers.reduce(
        (r, { vram }, i, a) => !i || vram > a[r].vram ? i : r,
        undefined
    );

console.log(maxIndex);
```

Comment: I used this in my project. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like below

```js
var controllers = {
    0: {
        vram: 4096
    },
    1: {
        vram: 1024
    },
    2: {
        vram: 1024
    }
};

var max = -999999,
  maxKey = -1;


for(var key in controllers) {
  if(controllers[key]['vram'] > max) {
    max = controllers[key]['vram'];
    maxKey = key;
  }
}

console.log(maxKey);
console.log(max);
```

Comment: I think `the index of the sub-array with the most vram` means He needs maximum `vram` and its key! @Luca

Comment: That's incorrect @Saeed.Ataee - I just need the index.

Comment: Use just `maxKey`. What is the problem? @GrumpyCrouton

Comment: No, I was just replying to your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to get the the highest value then the following function in the code snippet will do what you need:

```js
const myArray = [
  {vram: 100},
  {vram: 200},
  {vram: 150}
]

function getHighestVram(array){
  let highestVram = 0;
  for (i in array){
    if(array[i].vram > highestVram) {
      highestVram = array[i].vram;
    }
  }
  return highestVram;
}
    
const maxVram = getHighestVram(myArray);

console.log(maxVram);
```

If you want to find the index with the highest vram you can use a similar function. Like this:

```js
const myArray = [
  {vram: 100},
  {vram: 200},
  {vram: 150}
]

function getHighestVram(array){
  let highestVram = 0;
  let highestVramIndex;
  for (i in array){
    if(array[i].vram > highestVram) {
      highestVram = array[i].vram;
      highestVramIndex = i;
    }
  }
  return highestVramIndex;
}
    
const maxVramIndex = getHighestVram(myArray);

console.log(maxVramIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate the `controllers` Object, and check each `vram` value, storing always the highest one, would do the trick

```js
let controllers =  [
    {"vram":4095},  // index 0
    {"vram":1024},  // index 1
    {"vram":55555}, // index 2
    {"vram":123}    // index 3...
];

let max = 0;
for(let i in controllers){ 
    if(controllers[i].vram > controllers[max].vram ) max = i
}

console.log(max); // outputs 2
```

Comment: This was my original plan, but wanted to know if there was a better/more effecient way. Either way, thank you for the answer!