# get javascript object out of array based on a field

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In an array of objects, I'd like to select the one that has the largest value in one of it's fields.

I get how to select the value itself:

```
Math.max.apply(Math, list.map(function (o) { return o.DisplayAQI; }))
```

... but I am not sure how to do the above but return the object itself.

Comment: share the object

Comment: `.reduce` operator will do great job to find largest value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the max value of an attribute in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020796/finding-the-max-value-of-an-attribute-in-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to get the object with the highest `DisplayAQI`

```js
let list = [ {DisplayAQI : 20}, {DisplayAQI : 100}, {DisplayAQI : 200}, {DisplayAQI : 10} ];

let result = list.reduce((c, v) => c.DisplayAQI > v.DisplayAQI ? c : v);

console.log(result);
```

Doc: [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: good solution, as the first thing that hit my mind after listening the question was sorting. But, we can exploit reduce in this case to achieve the result.

Comment: Sorting is very slow compared to reduce @AbhishekKumar

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> myObjectArray.sort ( (myObject1, myObject2) => {
> return myObject1.field - myObject2.field
> })[0]
> ```
>
> Simply **sort the array according to your field, and get the zero index element.**

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can sort the array of object in descending order and the get the element from the `0th` index

```js
let list = [{
  DisplayAQI: 20
}, {
  DisplayAQI: 100
}, {
  DisplayAQI: 200
}, {
  DisplayAQI: 10
}];

let result = list.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.DisplayAQI - a.DisplayAQI

})[0];
console.log(result)
```