# Most efficient way to find max/min element in array of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, web

I'd like to know how Can I return the min/max element in array of array Efficiently. I know I can do a loop throught the array but I think there may be a better option.

```
let tab= [2];
tab[0] = [{name :"book", value : 8}, {name :"cake", value : 2}]
tab[1] ... etc
```

I want to find the min or max value in this array for example.

> I go with Math.max.apply to do that since it's referencing the array while reduce duplicates it. But if you don't care about that you totally should use reduce like it is said below.

Comment: Sort and get first element

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz This is very inefficient way to find min/max values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the max value of an attribute in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020796/finding-the-max-value-of-an-attribute-in-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Is the array sorted? If so, you can grab the first (or last) value to get what you need. Is the array not sorted? You need to either do a linear scan for O(n) or sort it which is unlikely to give you O(n). There is no magical way to know what is the smallest value in an unsorted array without checking everything.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko `O(n log(n))` is not bad at all :l

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz But it is worse than straight forward loop which is only `O(n)`

Comment: @CalvinNunes there seems to be only one answer on that page that is efficient. The accepted answer, for example, isn't as it goes through the array once, builds another array and then goes through it again for an O(2n) in both time and space complexity.

Comment: @vlaz "There is no magical way to know what is the smallest value in an unsorted array without checking everything." there is sort of magical way to do it in `O(sqrt(n))` [if you have a quantum computer](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9607014.pdf) :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko woah interesting paper. I love the sentence "The probability of success can be improved by running the algorithm c times" :D

Comment: @vlaz As usually when it comes to quantum computation. But anyway `c` is independent of `n` :)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, nice paper Yury :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing it. The first one is to reduce the array maintaining the max/min value:

```js
let tab= [2];
tab[0] = [{name :"book", value : 8}, {name :"cake", value : 2}]
tab[1] = [{name :"apple", value : 1}, {name :"spaceship", value : 200}]

console.log(
  tab.map(a=>a.reduce((a,b)=>a.value>b.value?a:b,{})).reduce((a,b)=>a.value>b.value?a:b,{})
)
```

This can be easier if we flatten the array as follow

```js
let tab= [2];
tab[0] = [{name :"book", value : 8}, {name :"cake", value : 2}]
tab[1] = [{name :"apple", value : 1}, {name :"spaceship", value : 200}]

console.log(
  [].concat.apply([], tab).reduce((a,b)=>a.value>b.value?a:b,{})
)
```

Those above functions get the max value, to get the min simply change `a.value>b.value` to `a.value<b.value`. Also, those functions has a time complexity of `O(n)` so with larger arrays it will work faster.

---

The other way is to sort and get the first/last value

```js
let tab= [2];
tab[0] = [{name :"book", value : 8}, {name :"cake", value : 2}]
tab[1] = [{name :"apple", value : 1}, {name :"spaceship", value : 200}]

console.log(
  [].concat.apply([], tab).sort((a,b)=>b.value-a.value)[0]
)
```

However this method is more complex as it sorts the array first (O(n log n)) and then gets the first or last element (O(1)).

Comment: `Also, those functions has a time complexity of O(n)` but the second technique makes an entirely new array. Moreover, with a large enough input array of arrays, it would be growing and *resizing* which can add a significant overhead in addition to the space complexity required for using memory for the second array. It's therefore not as performant as just statically walking the array of arrays. The first technique could be re-written as a recursive function, which would handle arbitrary depth of arrays and would even be pretty simple to read.

Comment: This [jsPerf test](https://jsperf.com/native-array-methods-vs-for-loop/1) shows how native array methods are slower than basic for loops.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like it depends on external factors then.

Comment: Indeed I have larger arrays, that's why I was digging the question. I will try both of them in order to compare their time execution.

Comment: Finally, I rather use Math.max.apply to get it since reduce "duplicates" the array while apply references it