# PHP JS how to search max value of column of CSV file

Tags: javascript, php

if i may i'd like to ask how to search a max value of column of CSV file using PHP or Javascipt,

this is my csv file table:

```
image,category,prob
"data/test1.jpg",zero1,0.947648
"data/test1.jpg",zero1,0.957323
"data/test1.jpg",zero1,0.955677
"data/test1.jpg",zero1,0.951940
"data/test1.jpg",zero1,0.950025
```

i'd like to find the highest value of prob column and print the category value of it.

output i looking for is like this:

```
zero1,0.957323
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP you could use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to read the data:

```
$handle = fopen("test.csv", "r");
// read the headers
$data = fgetcsv($handle);
// read the data
$max_prob = 0;
$category_max = '';
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
    if ($data[2] > $max_prob) {
        $max_prob = $data[2];
        $category_max = $data[1];
    }
}
echo "max prob value is $max_prob for category $category_max\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so typically on SO, you want to say what you've tried, what error you've gotten etc, otherwise your question may get deleted. But, here goes:

```
var originalString = `"data/test1.jpg",zero1,0.947648
    "data/test1.jpg",zero1,0.957323
    "data/test1.jpg",zero1,0.955677
    "data/test1.jpg",zero1,0.951940
    "data/test1.jpg",zero1,0.950025`;

var oneDArray = originalString.split('\n\r'); // split on the return characters, you may have to play with this to get it to work.

var twoDAttay = oneDArray.map( line => line.split(",") ); // make an array of 3 elements for each line, split by the commas.
```

So at this point you have this:

```
twoDArray = [
    ["data/test1.jpg",zero1,0.947648],
    ["data/test1.jpg",zero1,0.957323],
    ["data/test1.jpg",zero1,0.955677],
    ["data/test1.jpg",zero1,0.951940],
    ["data/test1.jpg",zero1,0.950025]
];
```

And all your numbers are in the `2` spot of each inner array. Now we're ready to find the maximum number, we just need to get the numbers in their own array:

```
var numArray = twoDArray.map( line => Number( line[2] )); // get only the numbers
var maxNum = Math.max( ...numArray );   // find the maximum number
var index = numArray.indexOf( maxNum ); // find the index of the max number, this will correspond to the oneDArray.
var maxLine = oneDarray[ index ];       // This is your answer
```

But after you get the 2-D array, there's many ways you can do it: [Finding the max value of an attribute in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020796/finding-the-max-value-of-an-attribute-in-an-array-of-objects). Use the version that makes the most sense to you. The hardest part is going to be cleaning your data into a format that js can understand - those quoted and unquoted strings are going to be an issue.