# Get the highest value from a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, max

I'm trying to get the `player` with the highest `rating` from the following JSON object. I have two teams `home` and `away` and I want to compare all ratings from all players and return the highest `rating` value and the `name` of the player.

```
   {
        "lineup": {
            "home": {
                "starters": [{
                        "name": "Andreas",
                        "statistics": {
                            "rating": 6.38
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Carlos",
                        "statistics": {
                            "rating": 6.87
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "away": {
                "starters": [{
                        "name": "Felix",
                        "statistics": {
                            "rating": 7.20
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Daniel",
                        "statistics": {
                            "rating": 4.87
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

*Keep in mind that my JSON includes 30 `players` with their `ratings` and not 4*

What I've tried so far.

Attempt #1:

I've tried to get the `max` from `home` and `away` team and then compare these two values and get the highest, for some reason it doesn't return the maximum value on each team. Ex for team `home` returns the `player` with the `rating 6.38` instead the other one.

```
//Home
$max = max($decode_one['lineup']['home']['starters']);
$finalVal = $max['statistics']['rating']; 

//Away
$max1 = max($decode_one['lineup']['away']['starters']);
$finalVal1 = $max1['statistics']['rating'];
```

Attempt #2:

Here I've added the ratings inside to a new array and then with a loop got the max value from the array. The 2 issues that I have is first the JSON includes 30 players, 15 from `home` and 15 `away` for some reason it puts only the 15 players from `home`  and not from both. I think that is because the keys from each team are the same (0-14) and the other issue I want as well to return `name` of the selected `player`.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($decode_one['lineup'] as $homeOrAway) {
    foreach ($homeOrAway as $startersOrSubs) {
        foreach ($startersOrSubs as $key => $value) {
            $result[$key['rating']][]  = $value['statistics']['rating'];            
        }
    }
}

foreach ($result as $key => $maxValue) {
    echo "{$key}: " . max($maxValue) . "\n";
}
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: [No such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Calling `max` directly on those `starters` arrays makes no sense - you do not have simple numeric values in there, you have objects.

Comment: try looking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020796/finding-the-max-value-of-an-attribute-in-an-array-of-objects

Comment: This will get you object having highest rating `Object.values(obj.lineup).flatMap(k=>k.starters).sort((a,b)=>b.statistics.rating-a.statistics.rating)[0]`

Answer (score 2):

PHP version, using `array_reduce` to find the maximum element in the combined array of players from both “home” and “away”:

```
$max = array_reduce(
  array_merge(
    $decode_one['lineup']['home']['starters'],
    $decode_one['lineup']['away']['starters']
  ),
  function($carry, $item) {
    if( $carry === NULL) {
      return $item;
    }
    else {
      return $carry['statistics']['rating'] > $item['statistics']['rating'] ?
        $carry : $item;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the PHP solution it works as I wanted. I'm facing a small issue, sometimes some players don't have a rating value and  it returns me the error `Undefined index: rating`. I've tried to check if there is `['statistics']['rating']` without success.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// A JS solution

getHighestRating = obj => {
    let starters = obj.lineup.home.starters.concat(obj.lineup.away.starters), highestRating = 0;
    for(const player of starters){
        highestRating = highestRating < player.statistics.rating ? player.statistics.rating : highestRating;
    }
    return highestRating;
}
getHighestRating(obj);

// Hope this will help
```