# Error: Cannot read the property 'nota' of undefined. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, undefined

Can you help me with this error:
"Cannot read the property 'nota' of undefined. "

```js
const arrayN = [ 
    {nome: "Rapha", nota: 10},
    {nome: "Renan", nota: 8},
    {nome: "Stefani", nota: 12}
    ];

function maiorNota(alunos) {
    // Encontrando a maior nota no vetor turma.
    let maior = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < alunos.length; i++) {
        if (alunos[i].nota > alunos[i+1].nota || alunos[i].nota > maior) {
           maior =  alunos[i];
        }  
    } return maior;
}
const melhor = maiorNota(arrayN)

console.log(melhor)
```

Comment: It looks to me like you do not need the condition `alunos[i].nota > alunos[i+1].nota`. In which case, you might find [Finding the max value of an attribute in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020796/finding-the-max-value-of-an-attribute-in-an-array-of-objects) interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Missleading Error

So the error is a bit missleading, but you should be aware when you do comparison with **indice +1** because it could be that you try to access an element which **is not existing**.

In **Java** for example this would throw an *index out of bounds exception* which says more then "Cannot read property 'nota' of undefined".

### Solution

If you would like to do a comparison with the next element then one solution is to update your condition in the for-loop and don't run to the end of the array instead run to the end-1 of the array.

In your last iteration step then you do the comparison with element at i with element at position i+1.

```js
const arrayN = [{
    nome: "Rapha",
    nota: 10
  },
  {
    nome: "Renan",
    nota: 8
  },
  {
    nome: "Stefani",
    nota: 12
  }
];

function maiorNota(alunos) {
  // Encontrando a maior nota no vetor turma.
  let maior = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < alunos.length - 1; i++) {
    if (alunos[i].nota > alunos[i + 1].nota || alunos[i].nota > maior) {
      maior = alunos[i];
    }
  }
  return maior;
}
const melhor = maiorNota(arrayN)

console.log(melhor)
```

Answer (score 1):

You reached an index that does not exist. You need to verify it exists.

```
const arrayN = [
    { nome: "Rapha", nota: 10 },
    { nome: "Renan", nota: 8 },
    { nome: "Stefani", nota: 12 }
];

function maiorNota(alunos) {
    // Encontrando a maior nota no vetor turma.
    let maior = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < alunos.length; i++) {
        if (alunos[i] && alunos[i].nota) > (alunos[i + 1] && alunos[i + 1].nota) || (alunos[i] && alunos[i].nota > maior) {
            maior = alunos[i];
        }
    } return maior;
}
const melhor = maiorNota(arrayN)

console.log(melhor)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get to last iteration i +1 is going to be 3, and there is no 3 index, so it is undefined.