# Calculate max and average of JSON API result

Tags: javascript, json, api

I need to calculate `average` and `max` rating.

From my perspective this should use `map` and `reduce` for this purpose, but, I'm not sure if the JSON has the right format, or if it needs any sanitization.

```js
const
  myJSON = 
    [ { "page": 1, "totalPages": 2, "data": 
        [ { "title": "Developer 1", "rating": 4.7} 
        , { "title": "Developer 2", "rating": 7.8} 
    ] } ]
  ;
var Max_JSO = myJSON.reduce( (acc, cur )=> ((acc.rating > cur.rating)? acc : cur) );
var Min_JSO = myJSON.reduce( (acc, cur )=> ((acc.rating < cur.rating)? acc : cur) );

var Avg_JSO = myJSON.reduce( (acc, cur, idx, arr )=> {
  let
    sum = acc.rating + cur.rating,
    no = idx +1;
  if (no === arr.length) { sum = sum / no };
  return { 'name': cur.name, 'rating': sum }
});

console.log ('max =',  Max_JSO)  
console.log ('min =',  Min_JSO)
```

```
max = { page: 1, totalPages: 2, data: 
        [ { title: 'Developer 1', rating: 4.7 } 
        , { title: 'Developer 2', rating: 7.8 } 
        ] 
      } 

min = { page: 1, totalPages: 2, data: 
        [ { title: 'Developer 1', rating: 4.7} 
        , { title: 'Developer 2', rating: 7.8} 
        ] 
      }
```

I'm using this code right now, but I get a weird string as an output:

```
"max =", "{\&quot;page\&quot;:1,\&quot;totalPages\&quot;:5,\&quot;data\&quot;:[{\&quot;title\&quot;:\&quot;Developer 1\&quot;,\&quot;rating\&quot;:4.7},{\&quot;title\&quot;:\&quot;Developer 2\&quot;,\&quot;rating\&quot;:7.8}]}"
 
"min =", "{\&quot;page\&quot;:1,\&quot;totalPages\&quot;:5,\&quot;data\&quot;:[{\&quot;title\&quot;:\&quot;Developer 1\&quot;,\&quot;rating\&quot;:4.7},{\&quot;title\&quot;:\&quot;Developer 2\&quot;,\&quot;rating\&quot;:7.8}]}"
```

Is there any way to do this better?

Also, I need to not only read `rating` from `data` key, but also outside of it, as you can see on `var myJSON`

Like produce a resulting `json` like this:

```
  {
      "Developer 1": 4.7,
      "Developer 2": 7.8,
  }
```

MIN being `Developer 1` and MAX `Developer 2`

Comment: Do you want max and min rating for each page or for entire myJSON array?

Comment: Please provide a better example with input and output. It is difficult to understand here if you want one max value for entire `myJSON` array or for each object inside `myJSON` array. Same goes for average and min as well.

Comment: your title is **average and max rating** and your code is  **min and max rating** where is the logic?

Comment: It is so unclear what exactly do you want...

Comment: While calculating `max` and `min`. Isn't the conditon should be `myJSON[0].data.reduce` instead of `myJSON.reduce` like `myJSON[0].data.reduce((acc, cur) => (acc.rating > cur.rating ? acc : cur));`

Comment: @RaviKiran Hi, thanks, for the entire myJSON array, will update my question, but that's the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you are having in your implementation is that you are failing to account for the nested shape of your `myJSON` array (thus all the comments asking if you want per page or combined results).

You can combine all of the logic into a single [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) call and either [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your `myJSON` array to return aggregate results per page, or use [`Array#flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to pass an array of all pages `data` arrays for combined metrics.

```js
  myJSON = [
    { "page": 1, "totalPages": 2, "data": [{ "title": "Developer 1", "rating": 4.7 }, { "title": "Developer 2", "rating": 7.8 }] },
    { "page": 2, "totalPages": 2, "data": [{ "title": "Developer 1", "rating": 2.2 }, { "title": "Developer 2", "rating": 3 }] }
  ],

  aggregateData = data => {
    const { min, max, sum, count } = data.reduce((a, datum) => {
      if (datum.rating > a.max.rating) {
        a.max = { ...datum };
      }
      if (datum.rating < a.min.rating) {
        a.min = { ...datum };
      }
      a.sum += datum.rating;
      a.count += 1;
      return a;
    }, { min: { rating: Infinity }, max: { rating: -Infinity }, sum: 0, count: 0 });

    const average = sum / count;

    return { min, max, average };
  },

  resultAll = aggregateData(myJSON.flatMap(({ data }) => data));
  resultByPage = myJSON.map(({ data }) => aggregateData(data)),

console.log('Combined');
console.log(resultAll);
console.log('\nBy page');
console.log(resultByPage);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, thank You @pilchard

Answer (score 1):

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34087850/10161292) from Andy Polhill which explains:

> Find the object whose property "Y" has the greatest value in an array of objects

This is an example to calculate `min`, `max` and `average` for one page. If you need to do it for multiple pages, you can first calculate local values for each page, then, combine the data and find the general value.

```js
const json = {
  "page": 1,
  "totalPages": 2,
  "data": [
    { "title": "Developer 1", "rating": 4.7 },
    { "title": "Developer 2", "rating": 7.8 }, 
  ]
};

const max = json.data.reduce((prev, current) => (prev.rating < current.rating) ? prev : current);

const min = json.data.reduce((prev, current) => (prev.rating > current.rating) ? prev : current);

let avg = 0;
json.data.forEach((el) => avg += el.rating);
avg /= json.data.length;

console.log(max);
console.log(min);
console.log(avg);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it :

```
  const myJSON = [
    {
      page: 1,
      totalPages: 2,
      data: [
        { title: "Developer 1", rating: 4.7 },
        { title: "Developer 2", rating: 7.8 },
      ],
    },
  ];

  const Data = myJSON[0].data;
  const result = {};
  Data.forEach((entrie, index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      result.min = entrie.rating;
      result.max = entrie.rating;
      result.avg = entrie.rating;
    }
    if (index !== 0) {
      result.min = result.min < entrie.rating ? result.min : entrie.rating;
      result.max = result.max > entrie.rating ? result.max : entrie.rating;
      result.avg += entrie.rating;
    }
    if (index + 1 === Data.length) {
      result.avg = result.avg / (index + 1);
    }
  });
  console.log(result);
```

you can also use sort method with custom sort function passed as a parameter

```
  const myJSON = [
    {
      page: 1,
      totalPages: 2,
      data: [
        { title: "Developer 1", rating: 4.7 },
        { title: "Developer 2", rating: 7.8 },
      ],
    },
  ];

  const Data = myJSON[0].data;
  Data.sort((b, a) => {
    return a.rating - b.rating;
  });
  console.log(Data);
```

by changing position of a and b you can decide to sort ascending or reverse
and then take first element as min or max and last element as max or min.

PS: in case you are getting data from an api you might need to parse the data with JSON.parse() first.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of the developers using `flatMap()` then iterate that to update a `stats` object that includes sum of ratings in order to finally calculate average

```js
const devs = myJSON.flatMap(o => o.data)

const stats =  {sum:0, max: devs[0], min: devs[0]};

devs.forEach(dev => {
  const {rating: r} = dev;
  stats.sum += r;
  if (r > stats.max.rating){
      stats.max = dev;
  }else if (r < stats.min.rating){
     stats.min = dev;
  }
});

stats.avg = stats.sum / devs.length;

console.log(stats)
```

```html
<script>

var myJSON = [
{
    "page": 1,
    "totalPages": 2,
    "data": [{
      "title": "Developer 1",
      "rating": 4.7
  }, {
      "title": "Developer 2",
      "rating": 7.8
  }]
}];

</script>
```