# Get maximum value from many textboxes using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am having many textboxes, every textbox has some value in it. I want to get the maximum value from all of the textboxes. I don't know which jQuery I should apply in this. Please take a look at my try below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $('input[name="result"]').val(Math.max('input[name^="tt"]'));
  });
});

//it should give 76.4
```

```html
<input name='tt1' value='12.2'><br>
<input name='tt1' value='33.2'><br>
<input name='tt1' value='24.2'><br>
<input name='tt1' value='76.4'><br>
<input name='tt1' value='34.3'><br><br>
<input name='result'>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is `Math.max()` supposed to do with a string (`Math.max('input[name^="tt"]')`)? o.O

Comment: Get all values, parse them into actual numbers and then use `Math.max()`

Comment: Dupe (concept) of: [Finding the max value of an attribute in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020796/finding-the-max-value-of-an-attribute-in-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Sir, please remove your vote down, because StackOverflow will stop my question asking if my question received negative votes. Please sir, remove your vote down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var allValues = $('input[name^="tt"]').map(function() { return +this.value; }).toArray();
  var maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math, allValues);
  $('input[name="result"]').val(maxValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name='tt1' value='12.2'><br>
<input name='tt1' value='33.2'><br>
<input name='tt1' value='24.2'><br>
<input name='tt1' value='76.4'><br>
<input name='tt1' value='34.3'><br><br>
<input name='result'><button>Click</button>
```

Notes

- `+'12.2'` is `12.2`
- `X.y.apply(Y, [1, 2, 3])` is `X.y(1, 2, 3)` ([see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply))

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an iteration:

```
let items = $('input[name^="tt"]');
let max;
for (let item of items) {
    let currentItem = parseFloat(item.value);
    if ((max === undefined) || (max < currentItem)) max = currentItem;
}
```