# How find max of an inner element in a list of key, values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, max

I have a list of items as you see below. The values for each year key is a list of 10 items but to make it short, I am only showing the first couple of them. How I can find the maximum of all inner "count" values? I have looked at various approaches but none has worked so far and perhaps I am missing something here. For instance, I really like some of one liners here but they didnt work for me [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020796/finding-the-max-value-of-an-attribute-in-an-array-of-objects)

Just to clarify that data is the result of a nest on csv file and it meant to be used in d3 chart and preferably no import library other than standard ones.

```
data = [
         {'2015': values: [{key: '0', value: {count: 45}},{key: '1', value: {count: 3}}, ... ]},
         {'2016': values: [{key: '0', value: {count: 67}},{key: '1', value: {count: 0}}, ... ]},
     {'2017': values: [{key: '0', value: {count: 12}},{key: '1', value: {count: 8}}, ... ]}
        ]
```

To better show how data looks like, here is the screen shot in case it helps clarification of the question.

[image]

Comment: Please use the appropriate tags. This is JavaScript, not Java. Also NEST is a ".NET client for elasticsearch".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could destructure the object like this by flattening the values array and then mapping to get the count variable.

```js
var data = [
         {"key":"2015", "values": [{"key": 0, "value": {"count": 45}},{"key": 1, "value": {"count": 3}}]},{"key":"2016", "values": [{"key": 0, "value": {"count": 67}},{"key": 1, "value": {"count": 0}}]},{"key": "2017", "values": [{"key": 0, "value": {"count": 12}},{"key": 1, "value": {"count": 8}}]}
   ]
   
   
  var num = Math.max(... data.map(d=>d.values).flat().map(v=>v.value.count))
  console.log(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```js
const myData = [
  { key: "2015", values: [10, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0] },
  { key: "2015", values: [10, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0] },
  { key: "2015", values: [10, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0] },
  { key: "2015", values: [100, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0] },
  { key: "2015", values: [10, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0] },
]

const maxValue = (data) => {

  // Setting an initial value to the lowest possible value in Javascript
  let max = Number.MIN_VALUE;

  // Iterate over each object in your array of data
  data.forEach(({values}) => {

    // Destructure the values from each object and then iterate over those
    values.forEach(value => {

      // Set the max to the higher over the current max or current value
      max = Math.max(max, value);
    })
  })

  // Return the max
  return max;
}

console.log(maxValue(myData))
```

What we are doing here is iterating over each object in the initial array.  Then iterating over the values keeping track of a current max.

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure appears to be incorrect. You cannot have `{ '2015': values: [...] }`. This would be the equivalent of `{ KEY: VALUE: VALUE}`. The browser appears to be inferring meaning from your code and creating an object out of it anyway, but it's not right.

You can do an object of objects and have named inner objects, like this:

```
data = {
    2015: {
        values: [
            { key: "0", value: { count: 45 } },
            { key: "1", value: { count: 3 } },
        ],
    },
    2016: {
        values: [
            { key: "0", value: { count: 67 } },
            { key: "1", value: { count: 0 } },
        ],
    },
    2017: {
        values: [
            { key: "0", value: { count: 12 } },
            { key: "1", value: { count: 8 } },
        ],
    },
};
```

Or you can create an array of objects, like this:

```
data = [
    {
        year: 2015,
        values: [
            { key: "0", value: { count: 45 } },
            { key: "1", value: { count: 3 } },
        ],
    },
    {
        year: 2016,
        values: [
            { key: "0", value: { count: 67 } },
            { key: "1", value: { count: 0 } },
        ],
    },
    {
        year: 2017,
        values: [
            { key: "0", value: { count: 12 } },
            { key: "1", value: { count: 8 } },
        ],
    },
];
```

How you get the highest `count` property depends on which data structure you use.

Using the array of objects, I would approach the problem like this:

```
// create a temp storage array to store "count" property of each
const countArray = [];

// iterate through the outer objects
for (const outerObject of data) {
    
    // iterate through the objects that are in the "values" array
    for (const innerObject of outerObject.values) {
        
        // push the "count" value to the array
        countArray.push(innerObject.value.count)
    }
}

// sort the array in place, with highest values first
countArray.sort((a, b) => b - a);

// display the result
console.log(countArray[0])
```

You could do something similar for the object-of-objects data structure, but you'd need different syntax for that.

Comment: Since you're touching every value in your `for...of` loop you may as well extract the max at the same time.

Comment: @pilchard - Please feel free to suggest a variation. I'd like to see your approach. Still learning new things every day here.