# How to select an object by highest property value

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
[
   {
      name: "first name",
      rolePosition: 85
   },
   {
      name: "second name",
      rolePosition: 91
   }
]
```

How to select an object with the highest `rolePosition` value? In this situation is `91`

Comment: this is not a valid JSON structure.

Comment: Check for Sort method in Javascript

Comment: Do you mean `[{name: "first name",rolePosition: 85},{name: "second name",rolePosition: 91}]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the max value of an attribute in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020796/finding-the-max-value-of-an-attribute-in-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: yup, I confused... sry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem can be solved with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as follows:

```js
const arr = [{ name: "first name", rolePosition: 85 }, { name: "second name", rolePosition: 91 }];

const result = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => prev.rolePosition > curr.rolePosition ? prev : curr , {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your solution.

```js
const arr = [
   {
      name: "first name",
      rolePosition: 85
   },
   {
      name: "second name",
      rolePosition: 91
   }
];
const numbers = [];
arr.forEach(el => numbers.push(el.rolePosition));
const max = Math.max(...numbers);

console.log(max)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.max`, `Array.prototype.find` to create similar function [_.maxBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#maxBy) lodash

```js
const maxBy = (arr, func) => {
  const max = Math.max(...arr.map(func))
  return arr.find(item => func(item) === max)
}
maxBy([{ test: 1 }, { test: 2 }], o => o.test)
// { test: 2 }

// or use reduce
const maxItem = arr.reduce(function(a, b) { return a.rolePosition >= b.rolePosition ? a : b }, {})
```