# How to get a max value from an array of Objects

Tags: angular, typescript

```js
data = [
    {
        "group": "banana",
        "Nitrogen": "12",
        "normal": "15",
        "stress": "1"
    },
    {
        "group": "poacee",
        "Nitrogen": "6",
        "normal": "6",
        "stress": "20"
    },
    {
        "group": "sorgho",
        "Nitrogen": "11",
        "normal": "28",
        "stress": "12"
    },
    {
        "group": "triticum",
        "Nitrogen": "19",
        "normal": "20",
        "stress": "12"
    }
];
```

I have this array to use in a grouped bar chart. I want to get the maximum value out of all the values, which is 28 in this.

Comment: do you just need the highest value or the value with it's key?

Comment: Examples of this in here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020796/finding-the-max-value-of-an-attribute-in-an-array-of-objects

Comment: Do you wish to get the object with the maximum `normal` value or do you wish to get only the max `normal` value?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative way to the other answers, you could sort your array from the highest to the lowest based on the `normal` property and select the first element:

```js
data.sort((a, b) => parseInt(b.normal, 10) - parseInt(a.normal, 10));
console.log(data[0]); // The element with the highest normal value
console.log(data[0].normal) // Or just the highest normal value
```

Answer (score 0):

I asume you want the max value from the `normal` property.

```js
const data = [
    {
        "group": "banana",
        "Nitrogen": "12",
        "normal": "15",
        "stress": "1"
    },
    {
        "group": "poacee",
        "Nitrogen": "6",
        "normal": "6",
        "stress": "20"
    },
    {
        "group": "sorgho",
        "Nitrogen": "11",
        "normal": "28",
        "stress": "12"
    },
    {
        "group": "triticum",
        "Nitrogen": "19",
        "normal": "20",
        "stress": "12"
    }
  ];
  
  const max = data.map(x => +x.normal).reduce((a, b) => a > b ? a : b, 0);
  
  console.log(`Max: ${max}`);
```

Comment: This definitely works for the `normal` property, but I'd rather ask for clarification from the OP first. (and in case it's only the `normal` property, the question is probably a dupe)

Answer (score 0):

Just extract all the numeric values from all the objects in the array, concat them to a collective array, and then find out the max.

```
const data = [
  {
    "group": "banana",
    "Nitrogen": "12",
    "normal": "15",
    "stress": "1"
  },
  {
    "group": "poacee",
    "Nitrogen": "6",
    "normal": "6",
    "stress": "20"
  },
  {
    "group": "sorgho",
    "Nitrogen": "11",
    "normal": "28",
    "stress": "12"
  },
  {
    "group": "triticum",
    "Nitrogen": "19",
    "normal": "20",
    "stress": "12"
  }
];

const getMax = (arr) => {
  const op = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const vals = Object.values(cur).map(v => +v).filter(v => v);
    return acc.concat(vals);
  }, []);

  return Math.max.apply(null, op);
}

console.log(getMax(data)); // 28
```

Answer (score -1):

Well below code works

```
var data= [
    {
        "group": "banana",
        "Nitrogen": "12",
        "normal": "15",
        "stress": "1"
    },
    {
        "group": "poacee",
        "Nitrogen": "6",
        "normal": "6",
        "stress": "20"
    },
    {
        "group": "sorgho",
        "Nitrogen": "11",
        "normal": "28",
        "stress": "12"
    },
    {
        "group": "triticum",
        "Nitrogen": "19",
        "normal": "20",
        "stress": "12"
    }
  ];
let max = 0;
let finalObject;
for(let  i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++){
   var newMax = Math.max(parseInt(data[i].Nitrogen), parseInt(data[i].normal), parseInt(data[i].stress));
   if(newMax > max){
       max = newMax;
       finalObject = data[i];
   }
   
}
console.log(finalObject);
```

Comment: This wouldn't compile just right, because Math.max(...) expects an array of `number` while you're passing an array of `string`.

Comment: sure, let me add parseInt @MikeS.

Comment: There has to be something better than an O(n²) solution.

Comment: @2189490 agreed, will be glad if anyone can share the answer. Looking forward towards  it :)