# JavaScript finding the highest value in array of arrays and printing the winning array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, max

I went through multiple StackOverflow answers and googled thoroughly before coming in here to help.

I have an array which includes arrays, as shown below.

Please how would I go about finding an array with the highest first value, in this example 30 **and print out the whole array which includes the highest value as the result**, so in this case the answer is `[ 30, '0.26', [ 'oranges', 'with apples' ], [ 'bananas', 'with apples' ] ]` ?

I know how to get the highest value, but I can't figure out how to print the whole array including the highest value.

Thank you!!

```
 let arr = [
     [
        10,
        '0.07',
        [ 'oranges', 'with apples' ],
        [ 'bananas', 'with apples' ]
      ],
      [
        20,
        '0.15',
        [ 'oranges', 'with apples' ],
        [ 'bananas', 'with apples' ]
      ]
      [
        30,
        '0.26',
        [ 'oranges', 'with apples' ],
        [ 'bananas', 'with apples' ]
      ]
    
    ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the max value of an attribute in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020796/finding-the-max-value-of-an-attribute-in-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: No it doesn't, because it only returns the single item which is the highest value, I need the whole array containing the highest value returned. I already found the answer and posted it in the answer of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to scan the array and find out the index which contains the highest number

```
max = -100//You can do something like negative infinity
highestIndex = null;

arr.forEach((arrayToSearch, index) => {

if(arrayToSearch[0] > max) {
highestIndex = index
}


})
```

Now hopefully you have the Element index which contains the max number you can just print it out...

```
arr[highestIndex].forEach(elem=>console.log(elem))
```

Comment: It says arrayToSearch is not defined, if I define it, then it says

 arr.forEach(arrayToSearch, index => {
     ^

TypeError: undefined is not a function .. the error arrow is pointing at forEach

Comment: I did not try and run this code. But it was missing paranthesis. You should learn more about functional programming in JS

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
const highest = arr.reduce((previous, current) => {
  return current[0] > previous[0] ? current : previous;
});

console.log(highest);
```

Source: https://daily-dev-tips.com/posts/javascript-find-min-max-from-array-of-arrays/

Comment: This is almost exactly the code from [the proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34087850/1563833) but instead of `.y` it's `[0]`     (and it's trivial to have renamed and reversed the order of current and previous in your ternary expression.)  Not different enough, IMO, not to be a duplicate.

Comment: You are right. I didn't see the second answer in the proposed duplicate, I only checked the accepted answer.