# Is using an array faster than having multiple statements?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm wondering. Is there a better performance with this:

```
$value  = preg_replace( array('/_{1,}/', '/-{2,}/'), array('_', '-'), $value);
```

than this:

```
$value  = preg_replace('/_{1,}/', '_', $value);
$value  = preg_replace('/-{2,}/', '-', $value);
```

This is just a very simple example.

Comment: Two words: profile it.

Comment: `$start = microtime(true); // your code; echo microtime(true) - $start;`. Repeat several times and see the result.

Comment: I'm on it. Give me a minute. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to benchmark efficiency of PHP script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291366/how-to-benchmark-efficiency-of-php-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As my test code:

```
$value = 'dfkjgnnfdjgnjnfdkgn dnf gnjknkxvjn jkngjsrgn';
$value1 = 'dfkjgnnfdjgnjnfdkgn dnf gnjknkxvjn jkngjsrgn';

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++)
$value  = preg_replace( array('/_{1,}/', '/-{2,}/'), array('_', '-'), $value);
echo microtime(true) - $start.'<br>';

$start1 = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++){
    $value1  = preg_replace('/_{1,}/', '_', $value1);
    $value1  = preg_replace('/-{2,}/', '-', $value1);
}
echo microtime(true) - $start1;
```

> 1.4254899024963
>
> 1.2811040878296

Comment: @insertusernamehere You're welcome. By the way, you helped me very much. I've optimized little part of my project that gave me almost half second difference that's really valuable in current situation. Thank you too.

Answer (score 2):

Using the microtime() testing method that PLB mentioned in the comments, you're looking at around a 0.3 second difference in performance. The second example is "faster".

Comment: Based on what? I tried doing a test and the second is faster.

Comment: I edited my answer to correct a logic error in my test. This is using the microtime function to echo out execution times. The second is faster by around .3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

To follow the calling I created a very short example where the replacement has something to do:

```
$value  = '1_2__3___4____5_____6______1-2--3---4----5-----6------';

$s_1    = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; ++$i) {
        $r_1    = preg_replace( array('/_{2,}/', '/-{2,}/'), array('_', '-'), $value);
    }
$e_1    = microtime(true);

$s_2    = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; ++$i) {
        $r_2    = preg_replace('/_{2,}/', '_', $value);
        $r_2    = preg_replace('/-{2,}/', '-', $r_2);
    }
$e_2    = microtime(true);

print $r_1;
print $r_2;
print $e_1 - $s_1;
print $e_2 - $s_2;
```

With this result:

> 3.69554805756
>
> 3.2879319191

As expected not a significant difference - actually no difference at all - as we are talking 'bout one million calls. Also it's interesting that the second version is "slightly" faster. I guess it's because creating and running through those arrays.

Comment: If your pattern is more complex than this example, take a look to the `S` (study) [modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: This sounds interesting for real complex issues. Thanks for that tip.

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting to note that I ran the two scripts and in my case the ones with the arrays were faster.

First Test

2.0891699790955

2.2491400241852

---

Second Test

3.2192239761353

3.4498269557953

---

System

**PHP:** 5.4.9

**OS:** Ubuntu x64

**CPU:** i7-3630QM

Answer (score 0):

Digging up an old thread. I've just ran the tests on MacOS and got these results using insertnamehere's function:

```
// Arrays
1.8200218677521

// Individual statements
2.4083371162415
```

So that's interesting in itself. However, I thought I'd go one step further and introduce a new test, because in the first test the arrays are being created on each loop. What happens if we create them before the loop runs?

```
$find = array('/_{2,}/', '/-{2,}/');
$replace = array('_', '-');

$s_3    = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; ++$i) {
        $r_1    = preg_replace( $find, $replace, $value);
    }
$e_3    = microtime(true);
```

```
1.7364799976349  // Arrays (created)
2.4450128078461  // Individual statements
1.5605390071869  // Arrays (referenced)
```

The results vary each time but naturally referenced arrays are even faster. Individual statements are much slower in my environment.

Important to note that simply reloading the page a few times, the two array match speeds tend to converge until there is little difference. Presumably this is PHP caching the compiled script - making a small edit and saving it gives more divergent values again.

So there's another benchmark for a production environment - how do the values change over time in a live script?