# Efficient way to save the images in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have got a MySQL / PHP code that:

1. encodes the uploaded image
2. saves it in database
3. fetches encoded base64 images from database, 10 at a time
4. saves in file system, and
5. puts the paths of the image in same database table

I tried with 200 images and it takes around 5 mins to do the task, but trying with 2000 images takes hours.

I generally don't think this is professional way of saving the images in database. How should I approach this to improve the efficiency.

Comment: Saving images to database is not a good idea most of the time.

Comment: Is that 'server speed'?

Comment: Why don't you perform some measurements? You could do your own benchmark using simple timestamps with high accuracy. Or have a look here for a more sophisticating technique: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291366/how-to-benchmark-efficiency-of-php-script

Comment: When you say 200 images takes 5 minutes, does that include the time it takes to upload the image as well of just the server execution time?

Comment: Insufficient information to diagnose the problem. And where are all these upvotes coming from, this is completely off topic..

Comment: MonkeyZeus, 5 minutes includes the whole process of uploading images to database and then saving them back to file system.

Comment: sigy, before I perform such measurements I want to know the parameters upon which the speed depends.

Comment: Processor. IOPS of the HDD. Network speed. Code you created to be executed by CPU, including utilisation of multiple cores in case of CPU intensive tasks. Storage engine used by MySQL, amount of available RAM assigned to the storage engine (to speed up I/O operations).

Comment: The speed depends *on everything*. Cumulatively on every little thing in the chain of actions you're doing. Since we don't know in detail what you're doing we can't even venture a guess what may cause the most problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do multiple activities to find out what is happening,

1.Monitor your system utilization for operation with 200,500,1000 images that will tell you does your system support that much load (do you have enough resources) if you are reaching 100% on memory,cpu,io etc then you need additional resources

2.monitor db queries/parameters and tune them if they are not tuned (check buffer size especially in your case)

3.storing images in database and again storing them on disk is bit heavy task according to me (see if you can optimize that logic), instead of storing it into database, directly store it on disk and store path in db

4.instead of storing images as it is if possible use compression which is very useful in your case. there are many tools/algorithms which will give you lossless compression (without hampering image quality). that will save your space and will improve your performance also