# How consuming is PHP Comparing to MySQL when summing rows

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I would have done it directly from MySQL, but I am working with someone else's code and I am bound to his mistakes.

Just out of curiosity, let's say I have 20 million rows in my database, and I sum them all in a PHP loop (doesn't matter names of columns).

How consuming is that?

For now I bypassed the issue using:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','2000M');
```

Let's try be more specific with an example:

Assume I have a table called `deposits` that has the columns `user_id`, `deposit_amount`.

There are two ways to sum the amount of all the users.

1) Using MySQL:

```
SELECT SUM(`deposit_amount`) FROM `deposits`)
```

2) Using PHP:

```
$deposits = getAllDeposits();
foreach ($deposits as $deposit)
{
    $sum += $deposit;
}
```

Comment: Very consuming.

Comment: Besides it risks script abortion when memory or time limits are hit. After all it means all those values have to be kept in memory!

Comment: To test this yourself [benchmark how long it takes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291366/how-to-benchmark-efficiency-of-php-script) each way and you will have your answer.

Comment: We're looking at probably tens of minutes vs. a few seconds.

Comment: Why am I being downvoted btw?

Comment: If you were to do it in PHP then you should at least use a cursor. Reading 20 million records into memory is crazy... and will probably not fit anyway.

Comment: @JacobCohen Probably because this is something you could easily figure out yourself.

Comment: Doing this in PHP is fine when you have a hundred rows, say. @DigitalChris has the right idea - try it yourself, and if it takes too long, then it's not the right way of doing it `:)`.

Comment: And yes, if you have to sum in PHP, at least throw the rows away, rather than trying to hold it all in RAM!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are going to read them all into memory and then doing a loop with a bunch of memory operations, very consuming.