# Mysqli Retrieve data and display them - best way

Tags: php, mysqli, logic, presentation, fetchall

Which one of the options below is better

**Option 1:**

```
//control file:  
$smpt = $con->query("SELECT id,name FROM customers");
//fetch all resuts 
$results = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $results[] = $row;
}    
$smpt->close();
//Note: PHP version < 5.3.0 so I can't use just $results->fetch_all('MYSQLI_ASSOC');
```

---

```
//view file:
foreach($results as $key=>$value) {
//display results
}
unset($results);
```

---

**Option 2:**

```
//control file:  
$smpt = $con->query("SELECT id,name FROM customers");
//fetch all resluts
```

---

```
//view file:
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
//display results
}
$smpt->close();
```

---

I am trying to completely separate the logic from presentation... Current I am using option 2 because with option 1 the script go through 2 loops. one to fetch data and the other to display them. But which one is better to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1** allows you to re-use the `$data` variable so you can display the results twice, but the cost of this is that you potentially have a large amount of data stored in a variable. You can clear this by using `unset($data)` once you are 100% sure you've finished with it.

**Option 2** requires less loops (only one instead of two) and doesn't need a extra variable to store the data. The cost of this is that the `while` loop can only be used once.

In the grand scheme of things, the differences in speed will be so minimal the user won't notice them, however if there are 20+ instances of this in once script then it could have a noticeable affect.

I would recommend **Option 2** providing that you'd only need to use the `while` loop once. Also, you could [benchmark your scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291366/how-to-benchmark-efficiency-of-php-script) to see how they perform against one another.

Answer (score 0):

It's always best that views only deal with presentation concerns.

So between the two options you've mentioned, I'd choose option 1 so you don't have to close $smpt inside the view ($smpt has nothing to do with the presentation layer).