# PHP echos blank datetime field

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my dilemma. I've tried referencing http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

but thats not helping me or i'm not setting up my code properly.

Here is my code.

```
$query =  "SELECT id,f_name, l_name, phone_1, phone_2, car_name, email, zipcode, ref_name, dateadded ";
$query .= "FROM customers JOIN carriers ON customers.carrier = carriers.car_id ";
$query .= "JOIN referrals ON customers.referral = referrals.ref_id";        

$select_customers = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_customers)) {
$customer_id = $row['id'];    
$c_fname     = $row['f_name'];
$c_lname     = $row['l_name'];
$c_email     = $row['email'];
$c_phone1    = $row['phone_1'];
$c_phone2    = $row['phone_2'];
$car_id      = $row['car_id'];    
$c_carrier   = $row['car_name'];
$c_zip       = $row['zipcode'];
$ref_id      = $row['ref_id'];
$c_ref       = $row['ref_name'];
$c_added     = $row['dateadded'];

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>{$c_fname}</td>";
echo "<td>{$c_lname}</td>";
echo "<td>{$c_email}</td>";
echo "<td>{$c_phone1}</td>";
echo "<td>{$c_phone2}</td>";
echo "<td>{$c_carrier}</td>";
echo "<td>{$c_zip}</td>";
echo "<td>{$c_ref}</td>";   
echo "<td>". date_format($c_added, 'd/m/y') ."</td>";
echo "<td><a class='btn btn-danger' href='customers.php?source=edit_customer&id={$customer_id}'>Edit</a></td>";
}
```

It will echo out a blank field. The col for the 'dateadded' is set as a *datetime* and a *value* of '2016-09-28 10:40:44'. Corrections to my code is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date_format` accepts as first argument

> A DateTime object returned by `date_create()`

Your `$c_added` is definitely not such object. I advise you to use plain old `date` function:

```
echo "<td>". date('d/m/y', strtotime($c_added)) ."</td>";
```

Comment: Or echo "<td>". date_format(new DateTime($c_added), 'd/m/y') ."</td>";

Comment: @jakubwrona, you can write your own answer)

Comment: @u_mulder, Thanks that solve my error. Can this be changed to a format mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: `d/m/Y`, I advise you to read `date` function manual, there you'll find all it's modificators.

Comment: @u_mulder. Yes. This helped. Thank again

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it, another one to previous answers:

```
echo "<td>". date_format(new DateTime($c_added), 'd/m/y') ."</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to replace:

```
echo "<td>". date_format($c_added, 'd/m/y') ."</td>";
```

in your code With:

```
echo '<td>' . gmdate('d/m/y', (int)$c_added['0']) . '</td>';
```

Or

```
echo '<td>' . date('d/m/y',strtotime($c_added)) . '</td>';
```

Just a note: Using `"<td>"` is slower, using `'<td>'` is faster

Comment: useful information. Didn't know about the difference. How 'much' faster is it ?

Comment: You might want to do benchmark to see the difference, please read [this Question/Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291366/how-to-benchmark-efficiency-of-php-script), it depends on what you do and how you'd like to do it.. http://www.phpbench.com has some standard test results but if you want to know exact info on your project you should benchmark the code by yourself

Answer (score 0):

date_format function formats DateTime datatype while $c_added is a String.

Answer (score 0):

RTM.
date_format does not take string as argument.

You should use something else, like

`date("d/m/Y", strtotime('2016-09-28 10:40:44'));`

Which returns "28-09-2016"