# What is the speed of Laravel DB:Seed in mysql..inserts/sec?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I tried inserting (via seeding) 1000000 into mysql table of about 6 columns of simple data types and took forever to load..well..PHP runs out of memory. After adjusting that, still...this goes forever. Any hints on how to improve this? What speed/how long does it typically take?

```
factory(App\User::class, 100000)->create(); 

return [ 'first_name' => $faker->firstName, 'last_name' => $faker>lastName, 'gender' => $faker->numberBetween(0,2), 'status' => $faker->boolean(0), 'dob' => $faker->dateTimeBetween($startDate = '-69 years', $endDate = '-18 years', $timezone = date_default_timezone_get()), .......]
```

Comment: Can you show your seeder code here?

Comment: Edited the question to include the model factory and the seeder parts...

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291366/how-to-benchmark-efficiency-of-php-script Short answer is that it also depends on your hardware and the size of the data you try to insert of course.