# Is it safe to reuse the same \DateTime in a loop?

Tags: php, loops, datetime

I need to format several thousand [`Y-m-d H:i:s`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) dates from [an API response (sample)](https://api-metrika.yandex.net/stat/v1/data/bytime?ids=44147844%2C2215573&metrics=ym%3As%3Apageviews&group=hour). I [used Xdebug to profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291366/how-to-benchmark-efficiency-of-php-script/8372751#8372751) these two approaches.

### What I have

```
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $dt = new \DateTimeImmutable($date);
    $value = $dt->format('r');
}
```

```
Calls                               Count   Total Call Cost
php::DateTimeImmutable->__construct 55800   183 ms  1,79%
php::DateTimeImmutable->format      55800   14 ms   0,14%
```

### What I tried

```
$dt = new \DateTime;
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $dt->modify($date);
    $value = $dt->format('r');
}
```

```
Calls                       Count   Total Call Cost
php::DateTime->modify       55800   130 ms  1,10%
php::DateTime->format       55800   17 ms   0,14%
php::DateTime->__construct  1       0 ms    0,00%
```

The latter approach looks slightly more efficient. Is it safe to rely on just [modifying the datetime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) instead of completely redeclaring it?

Comment: Does a difference of 53ms over 55800 items really warrant this…?

Comment: IMHO, unless you have a strong reason to squeeze milliseconds you should stick to the code that's easier to understand. Your algorithm is not about altering a given date with an array of dates, yet that's what the `->modify()` version suggest at first sight.

Answer (score 0):

We're talking micro-optimizations, your example with DateTimeImmutable inside the loop is slower because you create a new DateTimeImmutable object each time. It's faster when you create the object outside of the loop obviously. and yes modifying it on each time is safe!