# Which type of placeholder should I use for PDO for faster performance?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

From what I've read, the only difference between named placeholders (like :email) and positional placeholders (the ? placeholder) is that you don't need to worry about the order for named placeholders when binding your params later, while with positional, you need to be careful to order your params correctly.

However, I can't seem to find if one actually performs better than the other?

Which should I use for faster performance, or is there no difference?

Comment: You could measure, but it sounds like something that will be negligible in the grand scheme of your application.

Comment: *(tip)* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor

Comment: Isn't it even possible to make use of named and positional parameters at once? If so, how would that influence performance?

Comment: @hakre I dont believe you can use both at the same time.

Comment: Btw, I'm curious behind the closing of this? It seems completely logical to me to worry about which of two options is faster? I feel like that is a constructive pursuit.

Comment: *(related)* [Is micro-optimzation worth the time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470990/is-micro-optimization-worth-the-time)

Comment: @Gordon it's really a bummer that this is labelled as non-constructive. Just because you don't think micro-optimization is worth the time, does not mean that there is a solid answer to this question. Honestly, it was a pretty straightforward question, and now I won't have any answer accept "who cares". Bummer. That being said, I understand if there is a larger reason that I am not seeing behind why this question shouldn't be answered. Maybe I'm just not getting why it had to be closed.

Comment: @johnnietheblack the answer to all of the "Is X faster than Y" is a very poor fit for SO, especially when its micro-optimzations. The answer is always: profile it and see for yourself if it makes a noticeable difference in the context of your application.

Comment: @Gordon I suppose we'd just have to agree to disagree. I scan SO daily for ways to improve performance, speed, and better ways to do things - small or large, and have come across plenty of answers that point out strengths of doing something one way vs. another. But, as it is, I do understand where you are coming from.

Comment: @johnnietheblack: Actually the positional parameters must be faster because no complex naming is involved. Naming needs more memory and resolution than just positions which are already positional resolved. Next to asking a question, you should add your benchmark code and show what your tests have gathered and then ask your question, e.g. is this worth, is it correct, what does the benchmark mean etc.. In case you have not written a benchmark, start to write one first if you really care.

Comment: @hakre Hey, I appreciate the answer! Next time I will for sure add benchmarks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no noticeable difference. I'd argue that using named placeholders is actually slightly faster, but that's my opinion. I haven't done any benchmarking on the subject.

Like you said. Named placeholders allow for extra flexibility by not forcing you to remember the order of the parameters.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I know it's most likely negligible either way, but I have definitely been surprised to find out that some native PHP functions operate very poorly...and usually it's the reason behind having multiple ways to do something. Thanks!

Comment: @johnnieblack this answer is what you are looking for? In other words: you were looking for opinion only. Like Truth said he didnt benchmark and is only making assumption. It might be right, but it also might not be right. If that is what you are looking for then your question is not constructive.

Comment: I'd have to agree to that. I was merely pointing out that the difference is probably negligible, and that the difference in the methods results in a different form of effectiveness.

Comment: @Gordon Good point, and I'll take back my above certainty that this answer is right. I suppose I was a responding more to people wanting to close this question, even though I think it's valid. It makes sense to me to care what is faster.

Comment: @johnnietheblack it makes sense to care about performance but not on a thing like this. If you want to optimize something, use a profiler and find the real bottlenecks in your concrete application before you waste your time on micro-optimizations like this.

Comment: Well, if you look at a grander scheme, for example across an entire project, the choice to use one or the other COULD have a severe effect on performance in query heavy pages - if one performed worse than the other. And, as it has been my experience w/ PHP and MySQL, there are many hidden performance pitfalls that can occur if you just assume everything is a micro-optimization

Comment: @johnnietheblack yes, but the point is: in an application you got context. So you profile the application in its real world context and optimize it there. If you then find out that using named parameter over positional gives you a measurable performance boost it's great, but asking for it in general (e.g. outside real world context) is pointless, because you might use the supposedly faster params for a 2% increase in speed when improving your queries would yield 50%.

Comment: @Gordon I suppose I still don't see the harm in wanting to know if PDO prepares one statement faster than the other. Regardless of the yield of boost. In no way does it make sense to not care. The same way that using preg_match vs other methods is much slower and should only be used when needed. It's a small optimization that is good to know...

Comment: @johnnieblack well, then profile it instead of relying on us :)

Comment: @Gordon it'd be great to be able to tap the minds of a bunch of experienced people on this, but since I can't, I will definitely do it on my own :)

Comment: @johnnieblack there is a bunch of experienced people's opinion in the question I linked in the comments ;)

Comment: Well, this is getting into a very constructive conversation indeed (not). May I suggest you take it to chat?

Comment: @Truth nah, I'm done. Sorry for spamming your message box :)