# Having Script within a Script Src tag? <script> (JavaScript etc)

Tags: javascript, html, validation, optimization

Why does this not work?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.com/assets/js/jquery.js">
alert("Hello World!");
</script>
```

But this does?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.com/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Hello World!");
</script>
```

This is general across many HTML tags that pull from source. [Micro optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470990/is-micro-optimization-worth-the-time) is important in my situation and I am also curious.

Comment: If one solution works and the other not, it's not about optimization, let alone micro optimization. Just about programming.

Comment: But "micro-optimization" sounds cooler than "programming."

Comment: I noticed you don't have an account at [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), I will assume you haven't seen [this post](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript), it's worth looking for JavaScript optimizations

Comment: What exactly are you trying to optimize? Bandwidth? Lines of code? Client processing time? GET requests? Consider that if you serve jQuery from [Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jqueryhttps://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery), the client likely has it cached already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) (emphasis mine):

> If the src has a URI value, user agents **must ignore the element's
>   contents** and retrieve the script via the URI.

Answer (score 7):

from http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html:

"If the src attribute is not present, then the content text between the `<script>` and the `</script>` is compiled and executed."

As there is a `src` attribute, the content is not executed

Comment: This is present in the spec as well, e.g. http://developers.whatwg.org/scripting-1.html#the-script-element - "If there is a src attribute, the element must be either empty or contain only script documentation that also matches script content restrictions."

Comment: I wonder, is `<script type="text/javascript" src="path.js" /> valid? My guess would be no, but why? Edit: ah, found it, only in XHTML in compatible browsers. Still don't get *why* though..

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you define the `src` which makes it IGNORE the contents of the `<script></script>`

In the 2nd example you have 2 separate `<script></script>` tags, the 2nd of which is housing your code to execute.