# Array with many values or many variables, each with one value?

Tags: php, arrays

Which option is better to save server resources: Array with many values or many variables, each with one value?

Latter the array values will plan to use like this: 
`array($input[0], array($input[3], array($input[10]`.

Variables: `$input0`, `$input0`, `$input10`.

Which option is better to save server resources (is it worth to pay attention at all)?

Comment: and what if you have 100 variables? you'll write them one-by-one?

Comment: So as understand need to use array? Is it not as much question about server resources but question about design of code and fast/not fast coding?

Comment: Definitely use arrays.

Comment: About saving server resources: [Is micro-optimization worth the time?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3470990/1409082). Unless you have proof that your script is using too many resources, you shouldn't bother and choose the option that will make things easier for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on referring to a set of variables as a group you would need an array.  Other options would be [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) or string interpolation such as

```
$input0 = 'a';
$input1 = 'b';
$input2 = 'c';

// Note you must know the number of 'input' variables ahead of time...
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
  echo "$input${i}";
```

Nothing short of **atrocious** IMO.

Comment: Ugh. The atrocity factor needs more *emphasis*.