# Exactly, which MySQL queries throws results that need to my freed by mysqli_free_result?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to exactly know which of MySQL queries throws results.

I mean, I have read that there are some queries like INSERT and DELETE that don't need to be freed.

Exactly, which one of those I need to free? I don't want to be using mysqli_free_result in places which not makes sense at all.

I know that you don't really need to use it, but I want to make the program as best as I can.

Thank you all :)

Comment: The program can be pretty good and have a simpler source without unnecessary mysql API calls every few lines. There's also that famous line, "Micro-optimizations are the root of all evil". Just food for thought.

Comment: [**mysqli::query :Return Values**](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) : Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Comment: why not look into manual ? and until huge(immense) traffic Micro-optimizations  really makes no difference or in other word Micro-optimizations  for those who do not know how to add another ram (imho)

Comment: So you say I shouldn't use it at all because it's a waste of time, readability and effort, right?

Comment: here is good article regarding  Micro-optimizations http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2011/08/on-optimization-in-php.html

Comment: also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470990/is-micro-optimization-worth-the-time