# Regex to match one of lengths, but nothing in between

Tags: regex, string-length, maxlength

When I want to test if input string is at least length 10 and at most length 13, I use this pattern: `[0-9]{10,13}`

But how would you test if the string length is 10 or 13 and nothing in between?

EDIT: I see two dominant solutions:

1) Using length1 OR length2
2) Using length1 + optional characters of (length2 - length1)

Just wondering: are there any performance differences between the two?

Comment: Well, it's hard to define a search string for a question like this.

Comment: @still_learning nice finding :)

Comment: @ArmanBimatov you might check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470990/is-micro-optimization-worth-the-time/3471356#3471356) out and this [tweet](https://twitter.com/ircmaxell/status/370993140628344833) :)

Comment: Not quite the same question.  The nominated duplicate asks whether there is another solution.  This question asks about the performance difference between two solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be

```
^[0-9]{10}(?:[0-9]{3})?$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/lS0pC0)

Comment: Don't rip off the solution from a duplicate, you have the power to close it as duplicate :)

Comment: @HamZa Sorry to say but I didn't even see duplicate post or ans. I was trying to construct my solution. If you believe it's ok, if you not still it's ok. It may just be coincident. the other 4 ans are similar, in-fact same, that doesn't mean they have copied from one another!

Comment: I removed my answer since all people overflowed the question with almost the same answer, you've come with one that's not similar and I find it really creative if you found it by your own. But don't forget to "clean up" stackoverflow. Well you're not "forced" anyway, just suggesting ...

Comment: @HamZa Had I seen that duplicate, I would surely have removed my ans and posted the ans in comment. Now that nobody else has posted this option, I would like to retain it. I do not intend to flood SO with rep rip-off answers!

Answer (score 1):

use this expression `^((?:\d{3}){3,4}\d)$`

Comment: Actually, if you test it, it will return true for 12345678901 (which is 11 characters)

Comment: fixed it, please try again