# Writing JavaScript for minification vs. for optimization

Tags: javascript

By optimization, I mean for example deciding between using a basic `for` loop vs. `Array.prototype.forEach()` based on which implementation seems to go faster in which browsers, etc.  (And in some cases, this can extend to micro-optimization, which [they say can be dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3471000/2714730).)

Here is an example of what could be meant by 'writing for minification':

```
if(foo === bar) {
    return true;
} else {
   return false;
}

// writing the following instead, which reduces size by a few bytes

return foo===bar; //will return true or false, depending on what the statement evaluates to
```

Some could argue the using that `if else` statement is a little more readable at first glance, but I would say that the second way of writing it minifies better.

As far as minification, from what I understand, the big purpose in this is to reduce server response time.

**What is the balance between writing for minifcation and server response time vs. readability, vs. writing for 'optimization'?**

**Edit**
One might rephrase the question as *writing for optimization vs. writing to make the code 'minify smaller'*.

Comment: That's not minification, that's just a shortcut. There are tools to minify your code

Comment: I understand that.  Wouldn't the first normally minify to something like if(a===b){return true}else{return false}, and the second minify to something like return a===b ?

Comment: To me, this is a terrible example - the first choice of `if ... else` takes way longer to read, whereas `return foo == bar` is faster to read and understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two are not mutually exclusive.  You should use a well-known minifier like YUI Compressor or Closure.

Write your code to be readable and maintainable.  Then optimize it if necessary.  A minifier will work well on almost any code.  The extra effort to make something "minify smaller" is so small it's really not worth doing.

Comment: +1 Makes sense, thanks for the response.  "Minifying smaller" is a good term for what I meant in my question.

Comment: Great!  Glad I could help.  Please make sure to mark the answer as accepted if it answered your question :)