# Advantages of setting variables inside a boolean evaluation expression

Tags: javascript, lazy-evaluation, boolean-expression

On [the MDN page for the `wheel` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel#Listening_to_this_event_across_browser), there is a code sample which includes the following at lines 30-31:

```
function( originalEvent ) {
  !originalEvent && ( originalEvent = window.event );
```

The second line seems to take a number of shortcuts that rely on the way JavaScript evaluates boolean expressions internally. If I understand correctly, its purpose is to set `originalEvent` to `window.event` if no argument is passed. Its action is the same as the following:

```
if (!originalEvent) {
  originalEvent = window.event;
}
```

or

```
orginalEvent = (originalEvent) ? orginalEvent : window.event;
```

What advantages are there in using the construction from the MDN site?

Comment: Based on your question, you seem to have all the tools to answer this yourself :) Since all three versions of the code you've shown have the same result, it starts to boil down to: readability, code optimization, and developer preference.

Comment: Your last line of code is not equivalent to the other two, just for the record.

Comment: @Blindy: can you explain how the last line is different?

Comment: Sure, you have code executing even if you have a value in `originalEvent`. It might seem to you that it doesn't change the meaning of the code, but it is not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

> What advantages are there in using the construction from the MDN site?

Looking cool pretty much.

I was going to say terseness, but the following is just as short, and it's clear at a glance what's going on:

```
function(originalEvent) {
  if(!originalEvent) originalEvent = window.event;
}
```

Do note however that their sample doesn't rely on any "internal" order of operations or anything sinister. Operator short-circuiting (which is what this is called) is a very well defined and popular part of many languages, of which Javascript is just an example. You could write the same exact statement in C and it would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect advantage of MDN's way over the ways you suggested. It's a matter of style.

All of the ways you mentioned do the exact same thing.

MDN's way is a little more "concise", but other people prefer `if...else` statements like the one you noted for readability purposes. Depends on the specific circumstances, but I think in most cases, choosing between one or the other is a matter of style, and not necessarily [optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3471000/2714730).

Answer (score 0):

To add more obscurity you could also use

```
function(originalEvent) {
  originalEvent = originalEvent || window.event;
}
```

There are no correct way of doing this, and they are all perfectly valid, I quite often use the one above, since i think it it more easily readable (though many will shake their fist at me for doing it).
I also believe that you could get all method to go through most JSLint'ers with their default setting, so it really is a matter of style.