# Performance of operator '==' with boolean variable?

Tags: c++, operators

I guess this situation came across in every programmer,where we can use comparison operator '==',in my case situation is like this,a c++ pgm

code 1:This has been used in all files except constructor

```
if(a==10)
{
 //do something;
}
```

but i can do the same as above with the following way,
i set a bool variable to true when variable **a** becomes 10 in constructor itself,i.e

```
constructor_name()
{
 boolean variable_name=TRUE;//when a == 10;
}
```

then i use the following code in my all files instead of code 1,

code 3:

```
if(variable_name)
{
 //do same as first code
}
```

which is better for performance ,the code 1 or code 3.I hope i have illustrated my situation so than you can understand.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on a lot of factors, but looks like a micro-optimization to me. [Is micro-optimization worth the time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470990/is-micro-optimization-worth-the-time)

Comment: I highly doubt that you're going to get any difference in performance.  Simply write the clearest code and let the compiler's optimizer do its job.

Comment: Skipping the micro-optimization question, there are two big unknowns here. How often are these objects created? How often is this if statement evaluated?

Comment: let us consider ,the if statement is evaluated in every functions,i just gave a general thing,mainly that count will make a difference in performance.

Comment: Adding a second variable introduces a maintenance burden for, likely, an unmeasurable gain.

Answer (score 2):

**You shouldn't micro-optimize.** You will hardly notice any difference between your 2 version in performance (maybe you will save 1 CPU cycle), but it is **not** worth the time and effort, especially because nowadays CPUs are really fast.

**Only** optimize if you profile and find a bottleneck in your code.

Look at it this way, if you store the boolean variable in the class, it uses memory (1 byte) for maybe saving 1 CPU cycle. Depending on how often you create the class, that *can* scale up (even though the amount would still be ridiculously small). ***You maybe saved 1 cycle, but you lost 1 byte.***

If you wrote this in production code, I am sure that others would find it confusing (I would), and wonder why you put a `isTen` boolean in the class, instead of just comparing the value using `operator==`.

Also, there may be a bug if you change `a` outisde of the constructor to `10`, then `isTen` would still be `false`, but `a` is `10`!

Comment: the value **a** will not be modified outside the constructor.And thank you for the answer.

Comment: @SubSea but maybe it _will_, you can't really be sure what would happen in future :)

Answer (score -1):

I found the below thing would make a difference,

consider variable **a** is an integer variable and it takes 4 bytes(assuming 4bytes for int),then compiler has to perform comparision of 4 bytes of memory where as a bool variable takes 1byte ,i guess this makes a differance in performance.

Comment: A 4 byte integer would just be a 32bit word, which can be compared in one instruction in a 32bit system. A bool may even be implemented as a full word as well, the standard only says that it must be "at least" a byte.