# String data to structured string VAT number

Tags: c#, datafield

Our API is receiving VAT numbers as a 'string' data value without symbols.
e.g. 'BE0123123123' and should be "transformed" into a structured field: 'BE 0123.123.123'
input length will always be the same length and type.

Any suggestions on what would be the best approach?

Comment: What have you tried? Surely you've at least attempted to add spaces and decimals yourself? That should be pretty darn trivial if the input is always the same format.

Comment: [String.Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.insert?view=netframework-4.8)...

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Hi, I know there are many ways in doing this. But since this is a high performing API, and the speed is very important, i'm asking for some advice here.

Comment: Have you benchmarked something like that too see how expensive of an operation it is? Unless you determine that it's a bottleneck, you shouldn't yet worry about making these sort of micro-optimizations. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470990/is-micro-optimization-worth-the-time and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil.

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions, one of them can be regex

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(\w{2})(\w{4})(\w{3})(\w{3})", @"$1 $2.$3.$4");
```